# The number of mistakenly tagged questions is off the [mpchart]

Tags: support, retag-request

I do not have sufficient privileges so I am using Meta to ask to merge [mpchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpchart) tag into [mpandroidchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpandroidchart) tag.

Phillip Jahoda, author of this library, says on Github that he monitors questions with the tag [mpandroidchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpandroidchart) as can be seen from the Github page [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

There is no library called "MPChart" and there are <strike>30</strike> [65 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpchart) in the [mpchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpchart) tag that are all about MPAndroidChart but mistakenly tagged with [mpchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpchart). Can we please retag [mpchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpchart) questions to the correct tag [mpandroidchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpandroidchart) and delete the mistaken tag [mpchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpchart).

Comment: You can do this yourself.

Comment: I cannot. Creating tag synonym requires a score 5 for the tag.

Comment: Edit ~65 questions?

Comment: Trust me. I tried it. SO does not allow me to perform this step as I am not active enough in *this* tag.

Comment: You can edit any question, like I just did https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42042638/revisions

Comment: You do not understand. I asked to merge two tags.

Comment: You can simply retag those questions yourself, which is easier.

Comment: @Braiam I'll edit the ~65 questions. But afterwards, is it possible to burninate [mpchart]? We are still getting questions on [mpchart] up until yesterday. Should that be posted as a separate request after the retagging is complete?

Comment: @DavidRawson burnination is just removing a tag from all the questions, it isn't something special. Once you remove the tag from all the questions, it would need a 1.5k user to recreate it.

Comment: @Braiam thanks I didn't know that :)

Comment: I'll post an answer to this question when I finish retagging manually :)

Comment: Big effort but it is a not a solution. It can happen again that 1,5k user makes a typo. Make it synonym would be safier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I retagged the questions manually. The tag now has [no questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpchart) and, if I understand correctly, will be GC'd sometime.

If you will permit me an aside, [mpandroidchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpandroidchart) is in the need of some love. The same questions seem to keep getting asked again and again. It would seem one of the reasons is because no-one is surfacing useful content with upvotes or bothering to downvote trash (code dumps, "can i plz hav codez" etc.). It would be nice if users of the tag could upvote questions and answers that had the potential to be useful to other users *even if they aren't immediately useful to the user themself*. This would make it easier for people to find the answer they want.

I suggest that [mpandroidchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpandroidchart) questions that are just a picture and "is it possible?" or "how do I do this?" (i.e., just a list of requirements) are "too broad" in the same way that [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) questions that are just a picture and "how do i make this layout?" are too broad. I try and flag these, but perhaps it is confusing people in Triage because they imagine that the library is something like Excel where you can get a chart without writing any code. MPAndroidChart is a library complete with [javadocs](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/javadoc/) and a [wiki](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki) and good questions and answers in this tag should reference these.

Comment: Actually the tag still exists.It is empty fortunatelly.