# A list of tag synonyms which are not proposed in Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Stack Overflow is a big community with users from different backgrounds. In Stack Overflow, tens of thousands of tags are proposed by different users to annotate questions. However, due to the diversity of the human language, it is very likely that same-meaning tags with slightly different forms co-exist in the site (e.g., [pdfjs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdfjs/info),  [pdf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdf.js/info)).

Although I have seen a lot of tag synonyms, only part of them are listed in the [officially-curated synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms). But the [rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/synonyms) are too **strict**:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms.

With a [synonym-finding algorithm](http://ccywch.github.io/chenchunyang.github.io/publication/seThesaurus.pdf) and a manual check, I found a lot of tag synonyms on Stack Overflow. But due to my reputation score, I can only list them as below (Note the direction is decided by tag usage frequency, the more frequent one is in the right side):

[abtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abtest) --> [ab-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ab-testing)   is synonym
[access-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-point) --> [apple-push-notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications)
[access-point-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-point-name) --> [apple-push-notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications)
[account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/account) --> [accounting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accounting)      synonymised
[accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accounts) --> [accounting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accounting)     is synonym
[acs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acs) --> [accesscontrolservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accesscontrolservice)
[adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adapter) --> [adaptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adaptor)
[adc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adc) --> [analog-digital-converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/analog-digital-converter)
[administrative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administrative) --> [administration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administration)
[administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administrator) --> [administration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administration)
[ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ads) --> [advertisement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advertisement)
[advertising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advertising) --> [advertisement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advertisement)
[affiliate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/affiliate) --> [affiliates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/affiliates)    synonymised
[agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agent) --> [agents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agents)    synonymised
[aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aggregate) --> [aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aggregates)    discuss/disambiguate
[aggregator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aggregator) --> [aggregators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aggregators)      synonymised
[air-native-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/air-native-extension) --> [adobe-native-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-native-extensions)
[ajaxform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxform) --> [ajax-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax-forms)     synonymised
[ajax-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax-upload) --> [ajaxuploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxuploader)
[alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alarm) --> [alarms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alarms)    synonymised
[alassetlibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alassetlibrary) --> [alassetslibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alassetslibrary)
[alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alert) --> [alerts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alerts)    discuss/disambiguate
[alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alias) --> [aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aliasing)
[aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aliases) --> [aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aliasing)
[allocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/allocator) --> [allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/allocation)
[alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphabet) --> [alphabetical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphabetical)
[alphabetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphabetic) --> [alphabetical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphabetical)
[alwaysontop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alwaysontop) --> [always-on-top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/always-on-top)
[amq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amq) --> [activemq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activemq)
[analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/analytics) --> [analytical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/analytical)
[ancestry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ancestry) --> [ancestor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ancestor)
[android-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent) --> [android-internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-internet)
[ane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ane) --> [adobe-native-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-native-extensions)     is synonym
[angular-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-bootstrap) --> [angularjs-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-bootstrap)
[angular-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-controller) --> [angularjs-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-controller)
[angular-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-directive) --> [angularjs-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-directive)   is synonym
[angular-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-filters) --> [angularjs-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-filter)
[angular-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-google-maps) --> [angularjs-google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-google-maps)
[angular-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-http) --> [angularjs-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-http)     is synonym
[angular-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-module) --> [angularjs-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-module)     is synonym
[angular-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-if) --> [angularjs-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-if)
[angular-ngmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ngmodel) --> [angularjs-ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-model)
[angular-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-resource) --> [angularjs-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-resource)
[angular-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-routing) --> [angularjs-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-routing)
[angular-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-template) --> [angularjs-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-templates)
[annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/annotate) --> [annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/annotations)
[apn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apn) --> [apple-push-notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications)
[appbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appbar) --> [application-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-bar)
[appdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appdata) --> [application-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-data)    synonymised
[appdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appdomain) --> [applicationdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applicationdomain)
[appsettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appsettings) --> [application-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-settings)
[aquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aquery) --> [android-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-query)
[area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/area) --> [areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/areas)      synonymised
[args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/args) --> [arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arguments)
[arm7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm7) --> [armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/armv7)
[arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrow) --> [arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrows)
[artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artifact) --> [artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artifacts)
[aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspect) --> [aspects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspects)      synonymised
[aspnet-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspnet-compiler) --> [asp.net-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-compiler)
[assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assert) --> [assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assertions)
[assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assertion) --> [assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assertions)
[associative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/associative) --> [associativity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/associativity)
[asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asynchronous) --> [asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asynchronously)
[atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atomic) --> [atomicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atomicity)
[audiorecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audiorecord) --> [audio-recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording)
[audiostreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audiostreamer) --> [audio-streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-streaming)
[author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/author) --> [authoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authoring)
[authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authorization) --> [authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authentication)
[authorize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authorize) --> [authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/authentication)
[autocmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autocmd) --> [autocommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autocommand)
[autoload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoload) --> [autoloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoloader)
[automata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automata) --> [automaton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automaton)
[autorotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autorotate) --> [auto-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-rotation)
[avatar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avatar) --> [avatars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/avatars)      synonymised
[azuread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azuread) --> [azure-active-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-active-directory)      is synonym
[azure-api-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-api-management) --> [azure-management-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-management-api)
[backbone-collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone-collections) --> [backbone.js-collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone.js-collections)
[background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/background) --> [backgrounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backgrounding)
[backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backup) --> [backups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backups)      synonymised
[balloon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/balloon) --> [balloons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/balloons)
[batching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batching) --> [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file)
[beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beanstalk) --> [beanstalkd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beanstalkd)    is synonym
[beizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beizer) --> [bezier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bezier)
[binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binder) --> [binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binders)      is synonym
[bitmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitmask) --> [bit-masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-masks)   synonymised
[bjam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bjam) --> [boost-jam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-jam)
[bll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bll) --> [business-logic-layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/business-logic-layer)    is synonym
[blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blob) --> [blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blobs)      synonymised
[blobstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blobstore) --> [blobstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blobstorage)
[block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/block) --> [blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocking)
[blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocked) --> [blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blocking)
[boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost) --> [boosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boosting)
[boost-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-build) --> [boost.build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost.build)
[bower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bower) --> [browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browserify)
[brand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brand) --> [branding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/branding)
[broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/broadcast) --> [broadcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/broadcasting)
[brush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brush) --> [brushes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brushes)
[btle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/btle) --> [bluetooth-lowenergy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-lowenergy)
[bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bucket) --> [buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buckets)      synonymised
[buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buffer) --> [buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buffering)
[buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buffered) --> [buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buffering)
[build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/build) --> [building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/building)
[builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/builtin) --> [built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in)    is synonym
[builtins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/builtins) --> [built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in)   is synonym
[bulk-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bulk-load) --> [bulkloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bulkloader)
[bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bundle) --> [bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bundles)      synonym conflict
[cakephp-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-model) --> [cakephp-appmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-appmodel)
[callout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/callout) --> [callouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/callouts)    synonymised
[caption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caption) --> [captions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/captions)    synonymised
[capture-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture-group) --> [capturing-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capturing-group)
[cardio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cardio) --> [card.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/card.io)
[category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/category) --> [categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/categories)
[ccw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ccw) --> [counterclockwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/counterclockwise)
[cdc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdc) --> [change-data-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/change-data-capture)
[cdn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdn) --> [content-delivery-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-delivery-network)
[cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cell) --> [cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cells)      synonymised
[center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/center) --> [centering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/centering)
[cep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep) --> [complex-event-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complex-event-processing)
[chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chain) --> [chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chaining)
[chained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chained) --> [chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chaining)
[channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/channel) --> [channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/channels)    discuss/disambiguate
[char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/char) --> [character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character)      synonymised
[chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chars) --> [character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character)     is synonym
[chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chart.js) --> [charts.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/charts.js)
[checklistbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checklistbox) --> [checkedlistbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checkedlistbox)
[checkpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checkpoint) --> [checkpointing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checkpointing)
[chunked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chunked) --> [chunking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chunking)
[chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chunks) --> [chunking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chunking)
[ckeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ckeditor) --> [fckeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fckeditor)
[click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/click) --> [clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clicking)
[client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/client) --> [clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clients)      synonymised
[clisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clisp) --> [common-lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common-lisp)
[clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clock) --> [clocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clocks)
[clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clone) --> [cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloning)
[cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd) --> [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command)
[codesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codesign) --> [code-signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-signing)
[collaborative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collaborative) --> [collaboration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collaboration)
[collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapse) --> [collapsable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapsable)
[collate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collate) --> [collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collation)
[collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collision) --> [collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collisions)
[comet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comet) --> [cometd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cometd)
[comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comments) --> [commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commenting)
[communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/communicate) --> [communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/communication)
[comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comparator) --> [icomparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/icomparable)
[compareto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compareto) --> [icomparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/icomparable)
[compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compliant) --> [compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compliance)
[condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condition) --> [conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional)
[confidential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/confidential) --> [confidentiality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/confidentiality)
[config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/config) --> [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/configuration)
[connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connect) --> [connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connectivity)
[connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connection) --> [connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connections)      synonymised
[contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contact) --> [contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contacts)    is synonym
[contain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contain) --> [contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contains)    is synonym
[contenttype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contenttype) --> [content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-type)    synonymised
[contenttypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contenttypes) --> [content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-type)
[continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuation) --> [continuations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuations)      is synonym
[contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contract) --> [contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contracts)      synonymised
[control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/control) --> [controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/controls)    is synonym
[controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/controller) --> [controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/controllers)      synonymised
[controltemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/controltemplate) --> [controltemplates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/controltemplates)    synonymised
[convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convention) --> [conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conventions)      is synonym
[converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/converter) --> [converters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/converters)    synonymised
[coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coordinate) --> [coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coordinates)      is synonym
[coords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coords) --> [coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coordinates)
[count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/count) --> [counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/counting)
[covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/covariant) --> [covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/covariance)
[cprofile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cprofile) --> [profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/profiling)
[createjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/createjs) --> [create.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create.js)
[criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/criteria) --> [criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/criterion)
[cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron) --> [crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crontab)
[cruisecontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cruisecontrol) --> [cruisecontrol.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cruisecontrol.net)
[cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cube) --> [cubes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cubes)      should stay
[curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curl) --> [libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libcurl)
[curry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curry) --> [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/currying)
[curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curses) --> [ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ncurses)
[cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursor) --> [cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cursors)      should stay
[curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curve) --> [curves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curves)    synonymised
[customising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customising) --> [customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customization)
[customizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customizing) --> [customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customization)   is synonym
[customvalidator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customvalidator) --> [custom-validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-validators)   synonymised
[cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cython) --> [cpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpython)
[daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/daemon) --> [daemons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/daemons)      should stay
[database-connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-connection) --> [database-connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-connectivity)
[data-cleaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-cleaning) --> [data-cleansing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-cleansing)
[datacontract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datacontract) --> [datacontracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datacontracts)      synonymised
[dataformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataformat) --> [data-formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-formats)     synonymised
[datamember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datamember) --> [data-members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-members)     synonymised
[datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datareader) --> [sqldatareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqldatareader)
[datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datastore) --> [data-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-storage)
[datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) --> [data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.table)    should stay
[datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) --> [data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data.table)
[datediff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datediff) --> [date-difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-difference)
[date-parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-parsing) --> [datetime-parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime-parsing)
[dbconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbconnection) --> [database-connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-connectivity)
[db-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db-first) --> [database-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-first)
[dblink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dblink) --> [database-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-link)
[dbproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbproj) --> [database-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-project)
[debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debounce) --> [debouncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debouncing)
[decimalformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decimalformat) --> [decimal-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decimal-format)    synonymised
[decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decode) --> [decoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decoder)
[decompress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompress) --> [decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompression)    is synonym
[decouple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decouple) --> [decoupling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decoupling)     is synonym
[deeplink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deeplink) --> [deep-linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-linking)   is synonym
[default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default) --> [defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/defaults)    synonymised
[definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/definition) --> [definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/definitions)      synonymised
[delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delegates) --> [delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delegation)
[delimited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delimited) --> [delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delimiter)
[demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/demo) --> [demos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/demos)      synonymised
[denormalized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/denormalized) --> [denormalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/denormalization)
[destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/destructor) --> [destruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/destruction)
[detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detail) --> [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/details)      is synonym
[detailview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detailview) --> [detailsview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detailsview)
[detect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detect) --> [detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detection)
[df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/df) --> [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe)
[dfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dfs) --> [depth-first-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depth-first-search)
[diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diagram) --> [diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diagrams)    synonymised
[dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialog) --> [jdialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdialog)
[digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digit) --> [digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digits)    is synonym
[dih](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dih) --> [dataimporthandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataimporthandler)
[dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimension) --> [dimensional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimensional)
[dimension-reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimension-reduction) --> [dimensionality-reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimensionality-reduction)
[dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimensions) --> [dimensional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimensional)      discuss/disambiguate
[direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/direction) --> [directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directions)    should stay
[disassembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disassembler) --> [disassembling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disassembling)      is synonym
[disassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disassembly) --> [disassembling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disassembling)
[disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disconnect) --> [disconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disconnection)
[disconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disconnected) --> [disconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disconnection)
[discount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discount) --> [discounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discounts)      synonymised
[dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dispatch) --> [dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dispatcher)
[disposable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disposable) --> [idisposable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idisposable)
[distribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distribute) --> [distributed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distributed)
[distributed-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distributed-cache) --> [distributed-caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distributed-caching)   is synonym
[django-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-cache) --> [django-caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-caching)
[django-email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-email) --> [django-mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-mailer)
[django-mptt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-mptt) --> [modified-preorder-tree-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modified-preorder-tree-t)
[django-taggit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-taggit) --> [django-tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-tagging)
[django-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-tests) --> [django-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-testing)
[document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/document) --> [documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documents)      synonymised
[domready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/domready) --> [document-ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/document-ready)
[dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos) --> [denial-of-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/denial-of-service)
[doublebuffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doublebuffered) --> [double-buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-buffering)
[downcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downcast) --> [downcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downcasting)
[download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/download) --> [downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloading)
[drawrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawrect) --> [drawinrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawinrect)
[drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drive) --> [drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drives)    synonymised
[driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/driver) --> [drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drivers)      synonymised
[dropshadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropshadow) --> [drop-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drop-shadow)      synonymised
[dt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dt) --> [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime)
[dto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dto) --> [data-transfer-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-transfer-objects)
[dvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dvm) --> [dalvik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dalvik)
[dynamic-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-controls) --> [dynamic-usercontrols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-usercontrols)
[dynamicform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamicform) --> [dynamic-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-forms)
[dynamicquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamicquery) --> [dynamic-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-queries)
[edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edge) --> [edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edges)      synonym conflict
[edt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edt) --> [event-dispatch-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread)
[effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/effect) --> [effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/effects)
[ejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ejs) --> [embedded-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-javascript)
[element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/element) --> [elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elements)    synonymised
[emgu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emgu) --> [emgucv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emgucv)
[emr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emr) --> [elastic-map-reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elastic-map-reduce)      is synonym
[emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulator) --> [emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulation)      is synonym
[endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/endpoint) --> [endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/endpoints)      synonymised
[enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enumerable) --> [enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enumeration)
[enumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enumerator) --> [enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enumeration)      synonymised
[enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enums) --> [enumerators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enumerators)
[environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/environment) --> [environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/environments)    synonymised
[eol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eol) --> [end-of-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/end-of-line)
[equals-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals-operator) --> [equality-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality-operator)
[equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equation) --> [equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equations)      synonymised
[equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equivalent) --> [equivalence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equivalence)
[erb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erb) --> [embedded-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-ruby)
[erd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erd) --> [er-diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/er-diagrams)
[er-diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/er-diagram) --> [er-diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/er-diagrams)      is synonym
[esql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql) --> [entity-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-sql)
[evaluator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluator) --> [evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluation)
[eventlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventlistener) --> [event-listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listeners)   is synonym
[event-listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listener) --> [event-listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listeners)
[eventreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventreceiver) --> [event-receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-receiver)    synonymised
[eventtrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventtrigger) --> [event-triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-triggers)     synonymised
[eventviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventviewer) --> [event-viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-viewer)    is synonym
[exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception) --> [exception-handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception-handling)
[exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exec) --> [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execute)
[executequery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/executequery) --> [executenonquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/executenonquery)
[executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/executor) --> [executors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/executors)      synonymised
[explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explode) --> [exploded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exploded)
[exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponent) --> [exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exponents)
[extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extend) --> [extending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extending)    should stay
[extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extends) --> [extending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extending)
[external](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/external) --> [externals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/externals)      synonymised
[extra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extra) --> [extras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extras)
[extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extract) --> [extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extraction)
[fab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab) --> [floating-action-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-action-button)      is synonym
[facebook-authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-authorization) --> [facebook-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-authentication)
[facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facet) --> [facets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facets)    synonymised
[factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factors) --> [factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factoring)
[factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factory) --> [factories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factories)
[fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fault) --> [faulted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faulted)   synonymised
[faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faults) --> [faulted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faulted)      is synonym
[favorite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/favorite) --> [favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/favorites)      is synonym
[feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feed) --> [feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feeds)      synonymised
[ff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ff) --> [firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox)
[fiber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fiber) --> [fibers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fibers)    synonymised
[figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/figure) --> [figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/figures)      synonymised
[filebrowse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filebrowse) --> [file-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-browser)
[filehandle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filehandle) --> [file-handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-handling)
[fileinputstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fileinputstream) --> [fileoutputstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fileoutputstream)
[file-read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-read) --> [filereader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filereader)
[filestream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filestream) --> [fileoutputstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fileoutputstream)     synonymised
[filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filter) --> [filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filtering)
[finalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finalize) --> [finalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finalizer)
[fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fingerprint) --> [fingerprinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fingerprinting)
[fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixture) --> [fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixtures)    is synonym
[flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) --> [flashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flashing)
[fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluent) --> [fluentd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluentd)
[flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flush) --> [fflush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fflush)
[fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fold) --> [folding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folding)
[folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folder) --> [folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/folders)
[fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fop) --> [apache-fop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-fop)
[format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/format) --> [formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formatter)    synonymised
[formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formats) --> [formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formatter)   is synonym
[formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formatted) --> [formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formatter)
[form-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-authentication) --> [forms-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms-authentication)    is synonym
[formhelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formhelper) --> [form-helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-helpers)     is synonym
[formsauthentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formsauthentication) --> [forms-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms-authentication)    synonymised
[formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formset) --> [formsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formsets)    synonymised
[formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formula) --> [formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formulas)    synonymised
[forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forum) --> [forums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forums)    synonymised
[forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forward) --> [forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forwarding)
[frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frame) --> [frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frames)    should stay
[fsm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fsm) --> [finite-state-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finite-state-machine)
[fso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fso) --> [filesystemobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filesystemobject)
[fstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fstream) --> [fileoutputstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fileoutputstream)
[fulltext-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fulltext-index) --> [full-text-indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/full-text-indexing)
[gac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gac) --> [global-assembly-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/global-assembly-cache)
[gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadget) --> [gadgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gadgets)
[gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gateway) --> [gateways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gateways)    synonymised
[gcal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcal) --> [google-calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar)
[generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generator) --> [generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generated)
[genetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genetic) --> [genetics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genetics)    is synonym
[gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gesture) --> [gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gestures)    synonymised
[getelementsbyname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getelementsbyname) --> [getelementsbytagname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getelementsbytagname)
[getopt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getopt) --> [getopts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getopts)      should stay
[git-tf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-tf) --> [git-tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-tfs)
[glib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glib) --> [glibc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glibc)
[glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glob) --> [globbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/globbing)
[global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/global) --> [globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/globals)      discuss/disambiguate
[gmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmock) --> [googlemock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlemock)    is synonym
[google-account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-account) --> [googlesigninaccount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlesigninaccount)
[google-authenticator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-authenticator) --> [google-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-authentication)
[google-closure-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-closure-library) --> [google-closure-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-closure-libraries)     is synonym
[google-signin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-signin) --> [googlesigninapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlesigninapi)
[gquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gquery) --> [gwtquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwtquery)     is synonym
[gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradient) --> [gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradients)      discuss/disambiguate
[gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradle) --> [gradlew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradlew)
[graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph) --> [graphing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphing)
[graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphic) --> [graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphics)    is synonym
[group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/group) --> [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grouping)
[groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groups) --> [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grouping)
[guava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guava) --> [multimap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multimap)
[gwtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwtp) --> [gwt-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt-platform)   is synonym
[gz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gz) --> [gunzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gunzip)
[handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handle) --> [handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handles)      synonymised
[handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handler) --> [handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handlers)    synonymised
[handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handshake) --> [handshaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handshaking)
[hardcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hardcode) --> [hardcoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hardcoded)
[hci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hci) --> [human-computer-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/human-computer-interface)
[hdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdd) --> [hard-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive)      is synonym
[helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helper) --> [helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/helpers)      synonymised
[hextiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hextiles) --> [hexagonal-tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hexagonal-tiles)
[hiddenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hiddenfield) --> [hidden-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-field)    synonymised
[highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highlight) --> [highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highlighting)
[hijack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hijack) --> [hijacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hijacked)
[hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hint) --> [hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hints)      discuss/disambiguate
[hls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hls) --> [http-live-streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-live-streaming)
[hoist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hoist) --> [hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hoisting)
[host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/host) --> [hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hosts)      should stay
[hql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hql) --> [hiveql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hiveql)
[http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http) --> [https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/https)      should stay
[httpconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httpconnection) --> [httpsurlconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httpsurlconnection)
[httprequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httprequest) --> [http-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-request)    synonymised
[httpurlconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httpurlconnection) --> [httpsurlconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httpsurlconnection)
[identify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/identify) --> [identifying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/identifying)    is synonym
[il](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/il) --> [intermediate-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intermediate-language)    is synonym
[imagemagic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagemagic) --> [imagemagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagemagick)
[imagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagick) --> [imagemagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagemagick)
[implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit) --> [implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicits)      synonymised
[indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexed) --> [indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexing)
[indic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indic) --> [indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indices)
[infinite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infinite) --> [indefinite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indefinite)
[infinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/infinity) --> [indefinite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indefinite)
[info-plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/info-plist) --> [info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/info.plist)
[inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inherited) --> [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inheritance)
[initalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initalization) --> [initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initialization)
[initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initializer) --> [instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instantiation)
[initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initializing) --> [initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initialization)
[inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inline) --> [inlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inlines)      should stay
[insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/insert) --> [insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/insertion)
[inspection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inspection) --> [inspections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inspections)      synonymised
[inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inspector) --> [inspections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inspections)
[install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/install) --> [installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installer)
[instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instance) --> [instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instances)      synonymised
[instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instruments) --> [instrumentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instrumentation)
[int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int) --> [integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integer)
[integrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integrate) --> [integrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integrated)
[integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration) --> [interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interaction)
[integration-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration-tests) --> [integration-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration-testing)
[interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interactive) --> [interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interaction)
[interfacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interfacing) --> [interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interaction)
[internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internal) --> [internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internals)      synonymised
[interpreted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpreted) --> [interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)
[interrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interrupt) --> [interruptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interruptions)
[interruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interruption) --> [interruptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interruptions)      synonymised
[invoice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invoice) --> [invoices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invoices)    synonymised
[iocp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iocp) --> [io-completion-ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io-completion-ports)
[iojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iojs) --> [io.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io.js)
[ios-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-extensions) --> [ios-app-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-app-extension)
[ipc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipc) --> [inter-process-communicat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inter-process-communicat)
[ipcs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipcs) --> [inter-process-communicat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inter-process-communicat)
[ir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ir) --> [information-retrieval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/information-retrieval)
[isomorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isomorphic) --> [isomorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/isomorphism)
[italic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/italic) --> [italics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/italics)      discuss/disambiguate
[itemsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itemsource) --> [itemssource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itemssource)
[iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iterator) --> [iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iteration)
[ivar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ivar) --> [instance-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instance-variables)     synonymised
[jarsign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jarsign) --> [jar-signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jar-signing)
[jasmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmin) --> [jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmine)
[javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javamail) --> [javax.mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javax.mail)
[jeasyui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jeasyui) --> [jquery-easyui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-easyui)
[jil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jil) --> [jsonserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonserializer)
[journal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/journal) --> [journaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/journaling)
[jshint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jshint) --> [jslint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jslint)
[jstat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jstat) --> [jstatd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jstatd)
[jtemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jtemplate) --> [jquery-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-templates)
[jtemplates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jtemplates) --> [jquery-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-templates)     synonymised
[jwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jwt) --> [json-web-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-web-token)
[jxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jxl) --> [jexcelapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jexcelapi)
[kext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kext) --> [kernel-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel-extension)   is synonym
[keyevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyevent) --> [keyboard-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-events)    synonymised
[key-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key-events) --> [keyboard-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-events)      is synonym
[keystonejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystonejs) --> [keystone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystone.js)
[keystroke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystroke) --> [keystrokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystrokes)    synonymised
[kvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kvc) --> [key-value-coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key-value-coding)
[label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/label) --> [labeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/labeling)      synonymised
[labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/labels) --> [labeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/labeling)     is synonym
[lastinsertid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lastinsertid) --> [last-insert-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/last-insert-id)     synonymised
[launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/launch) --> [launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/launching)
[launchd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/launchd) --> [launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/launching)
[launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/launcher) --> [launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/launching)
[layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layer) --> [layered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layered)
[lazyload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lazyload) --> [lazy-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lazy-loading)
[letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/letter) --> [letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/letters)
[level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/level) --> [levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/levels)
[lf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lf) --> [linefeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linefeed)
[libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libs) --> [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libraries)
[light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/light) --> [lighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lighting)
[lights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lights) --> [lighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lighting)     is synonym
[limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/limit) --> [limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/limits)    synonymised
[line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/line) --> [lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lines)      synonymised
[listadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listadapter) --> [listview-adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview-adapter)
[listboxitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listboxitem) --> [listboxitems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listboxitems)    synonymised
[listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listener) --> [listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listeners)      synonymised
[local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local) --> [locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locals)    discuss/disambiguate
[location-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/location-services) --> [location-based-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/location-based-service)
[locks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locks) --> [locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locking)
[logfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logfile) --> [log-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log-files)   synonymised
[logfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logfiles) --> [log-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log-files)      synonymised
[lostfocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lostfocus) --> [lost-focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lost-focus)    synonymised
[lr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lr) --> [left-recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/left-recursion)
[lts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lts) --> [linq-to-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linq-to-sql)
[lwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lwp) --> [libwww-perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libwww-perl)
[lxc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lxc) --> [linux-containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-containers)
[m2e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m2e) --> [m2eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m2eclipse)   is synonym
[manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manual) --> [manuals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manuals)      synonymised
[mapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapper) --> [mappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mappers)      synonymised
[mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapping) --> [mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mappings)    synonymised
[margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/margin) --> [margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/margins)      discuss/disambiguate
[marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marker) --> [markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markers)      discuss/disambiguate
[mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mask) --> [masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masking)
[match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/match) --> [matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matching)
[materialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/materialize) --> [materialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/materialized)
[mathjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjs) --> [math.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math.js)
[maven-ear-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-ear-plugin) --> [maven-war-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-war-plugin)
[measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/measure) --> [measurement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/measurement)     synonymised
[measures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/measures) --> [measurement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/measurement)    is synonym
[mediaelement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediaelement) --> [mediaelement.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediaelement.js)
[member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/member) --> [members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/members)      synonymised
[memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memoization) --> [memorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memorization)
[menuitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menuitem) --> [menu-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu-items)     synonym conflict
[message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/message) --> [messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messages)    synonymised
[metatag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metatag) --> [meta-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags)   is synonym
[meteor-accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor-accounts) --> [meteor-useraccounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor-useraccounts)
[metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metric) --> [metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metrics)      is synonym
[migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration) --> [migrating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrating)
[mingw64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw64) --> [mingw-w64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw-w64)   is synonym
[minimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minimization) --> [maximization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maximization)
[minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minimize) --> [minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minimized)
[minmax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minmax) --> [minimax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minimax)
[mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirror) --> [mirroring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mirroring)
[moc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moc) --> [managedobjectcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/managedobjectcontext)
[model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model) --> [modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modeling)      synonymised
[models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/models) --> [modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modeling)     is synonym
[modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modifier) --> [modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modifiers)      synonymised
[modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulo) --> [modulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modulus)
[mongo-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo-java) --> [mongodb-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-java)     is synonym
[mongo-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo-shell) --> [mongodb-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-shell)
[monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monitor) --> [monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monitoring)      synonymised
[monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monitors) --> [monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monitoring)     is synonym
[mouselistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouselistener) --> [mouse-listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouse-listeners)   synonymised
[movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movie) --> [movies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movies)    discuss/disambiguate
[mpchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpchart) --> [mpandroidchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpandroidchart)
[mptt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mptt) --> [modified-preorder-tree-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modified-preorder-tree-t)
[mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mq) --> [message-queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/message-queue)
[msg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msg) --> [messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messages)
[msgbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msgbox) --> [messagebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messagebox)
[msgpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msgpack) --> [messagepack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messagepack)
[mtm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mtm) --> [microsoft-test-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-test-manager)      is synonym
[multi-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-database) --> [multiple-databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-databases)
[multifile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multifile) --> [multiple-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-files)
[multifile-uploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multifile-uploader) --> [multiple-file-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-file-upload)
[multilanguage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilanguage) --> [multiple-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-languages)
[multilingual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilingual) --> [multiple-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-languages)
[multi-monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-monitor) --> [multiple-monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors)     is synonym
[multiple-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-select) --> [multipleselection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multipleselection)
[multiprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiprocess) --> [multiple-processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-processes)
[multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiprocessing) --> [multiple-processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-processes)
[multiprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiprocessor) --> [multiple-processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-processes)
[multi-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-project) --> [multiple-projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-projects)
[multi-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-select) --> [multipleselection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multipleselection)
[multi-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-table) --> [multiple-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-tables)
[multi-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-user) --> [multiple-users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-users)
[multivalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multivalue) --> [multiple-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-value)
[multiview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiview) --> [multiviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiviews)    synonymised
[mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutate) --> [mutated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutated)
[mvcminiprofiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvcminiprofiler) --> [mvc-mini-profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc-mini-profiler)   synonymised
[names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/names) --> [named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/named)
[nested-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-query) --> [nested-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-queries)
[nodesets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodesets) --> [node-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-set)
[node-streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-streams) --> [node.js-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js-stream)
[normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalization) --> [normalisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalisation)
[normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalize) --> [normalisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalisation)
[normalizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalizing) --> [normalisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalisation)
[nose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nose) --> [nosetests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nosetests)
[nsnotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsnotification) --> [nsnotifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsnotifications)      is synonym
[nsview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsview) --> [nstextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nstextview)
[nszombie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nszombie) --> [nszombies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nszombies)      synonymised
[numberformatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numberformatter) --> [number-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/number-formatting)
[numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numbers) --> [numbered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numbered)
[numerics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerics) --> [numerical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical)      is synonym
[nwjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nwjs) --> [nw.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nw.js)
[odt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odt) --> [opendocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opendocument)
[oid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oid) --> [objectid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objectid)
[onactionexecuted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onactionexecuted) --> [onactionexecuting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onactionexecuting)
[onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onclick) --> [onclientclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onclientclick)
[opcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opcode) --> [opcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opcodes)      synonymised
[operand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operand) --> [operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operands)    synonymised
[operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operation) --> [operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operations)    synonymised
[option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option) --> [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options)      synonymised
[optionmenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optionmenu) --> [options-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options-menu)     synonymised
[orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orbit) --> [orbited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orbited)
[order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order) --> [orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orders)    should stay
[ordinal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ordinal) --> [ordinals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ordinals)    discuss/disambiguate
[osb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osb) --> [oracle-service-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-service-bus)
[osk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osk) --> [on-screen-keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/on-screen-keyboard)      is synonym
[ota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ota) --> [over-the-air](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/over-the-air)
[outputcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outputcache) --> [output-caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/output-caching)
[overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overlay) --> [overlays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overlays)    synonymised
[override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/override) --> [overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overriding)     synonymised
[overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overrides) --> [overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overriding)    is synonym
[p12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p12) --> [pkcs#12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%2312)
[package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package) --> [packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packages)    synonymised
[package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package.json) --> [packages.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packages.json)
[packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packet) --> [packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packets)      synonymised
[pagerjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagerjs) --> [pager.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pager.js)
[paginate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginate) --> [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination)
[paginator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginator) --> [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination)
[pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pane) --> [panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/panels)     synonymised
[panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/panel) --> [panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/panels)    synonymised
[panes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/panes) --> [panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/panels)    is synonym
[paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paragraph) --> [paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paragraphs)    synonymised
[param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/param) --> [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameters)    is synonym
[params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/params) --> [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameters)   synonymised
[parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parent) --> [parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parents)      synonymised
[parfor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parfor) --> [parallel.foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parallel.foreach)
[partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partial) --> [partials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partials)    discuss/disambiguate
[particle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/particle) --> [particles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/particles)      is synonym
[partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partition) --> [partitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partitioning)
[passwd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passwd) --> [passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passwords)
[patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/patch) --> [patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/patching)
[pch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pch) --> [precompiled-headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precompiled-headers)
[pcntl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcntl) --> [process-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/process-control)
[pdfjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdfjs) --> [pdf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf.js)
[pdfviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdfviewer) --> [pdf-viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf-viewer)    synonymised
[pe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pe) --> [portable-executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/portable-executable)      is synonym
[perfmon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perfmon) --> [performance-monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance-monitor)
[perms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perms) --> [permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/permissions)
[persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persist) --> [persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistence)
[persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistent) --> [persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistence)
[perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perspective) --> [perspectives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perspectives)    synonymised
[pg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pg) --> [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql)
[photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photo) --> [photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photos)    synonymised
[phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phrase) --> [phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phrases)      synonymised
[ping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ping) --> [pinging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pinging)
[pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipeline) --> [pipelining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipelining)
[piston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piston) --> [django-piston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-piston)
[pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixel) --> [pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pixels)    synonymised
[pkcs12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs12) --> [pkcs#12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pkcs%2312)      is synonym
[playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playlist) --> [playlists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playlists)      synonymised
[plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plist) --> [property-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/property-list)
[point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/point) --> [points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/points)    discuss/disambiguate
[pointcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointcut) --> [pointcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointcuts)      synonymised
[polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polygon) --> [polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polygons)    synonymised
[popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popup) --> [pop-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop-up)
[popviewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popviewcontroller) --> [poptoviewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poptoviewcontroller)
[port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/port) --> [ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ports)      synonymised
[position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/position) --> [positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/positioning)
[posix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/posix) --> [pthreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pthreads)
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post) --> [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/posts)      should stay
[powermanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powermanager) --> [power-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/power-management)
[powermock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powermock) --> [powermockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powermockito)
[pp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pp) --> [pretty-print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pretty-print)
[ppc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ppc) --> [powerpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpc)     is synonym
[pprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pprint) --> [pretty-print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pretty-print)
[precompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precompile) --> [pre-compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pre-compilation)
[precompiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precompiled) --> [pre-compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pre-compilation)
[predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/predicate) --> [predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/predicates)    synonymised
[preemptive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preemptive) --> [preemption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preemption)
[preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preference) --> [preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preferences)
[prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prefix) --> [prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prefixes)
[preload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preload) --> [preloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preloading)
[privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/privilege) --> [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/privileges)    is synonym
[procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procedure) --> [procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procedures)    synonymised
[process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/process) --> [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processing)
[processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processor) --> [processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processors)    discuss/disambiguate
[product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product) --> [products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/products)
[profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/profile) --> [profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/profiling)   synonymised
[profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/profiler) --> [profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/profiling)
[profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/profiles) --> [profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/profiling)      is synonym
[proj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proj) --> [projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/projects)
[project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project) --> [projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/projects)    synonymised
[proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proof) --> [proofs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proofs)    synonymised
[provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/provider) --> [providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/providers)
[proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proxy) --> [proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proxies)
[publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/publish) --> [publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/publishing)
[pwd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pwd) --> [passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passwords)
[pyunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyunit) --> [python-unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-unittest)
[qc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc) --> [quality-center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quality-center)
[qsort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qsort) --> [quicksort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quicksort)
[queuing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queuing) --> [queueing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queueing)
[quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quota) --> [quotas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quotas)    synonymised
[quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quote) --> [quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quoting)
[quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quotes) --> [quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quoting)      discuss/disambiguate
[qwebkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qwebkit) --> [qtwebkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtwebkit)    is synonym
[raiserror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raiserror) --> [raiseerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raiseerror)
[rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rate) --> [rates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rates)      synonymised
[ratelimit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratelimit) --> [rate-limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rate-limiting)
[rbac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rbac) --> [role-based-access-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/role-based-access-control)
[rdebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdebug) --> [ruby-debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-debug)
[rdms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdms) --> [rdbms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdbms)
[readability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readability) --> [reliability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reliability)
[readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readline) --> [readlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readlines)      should stay
[rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rebase) --> [git-rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-rebase)
[rebasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rebasing) --> [git-rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-rebase)
[record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record) --> [recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recording)    synonymised
[records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/records) --> [recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recording)   is synonym
[reentrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reentrant) --> [reentrancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reentrancy)
[refcounting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refcounting) --> [reference-counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reference-counting)
[referer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/referer) --> [referrer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/referrer)
[region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/region) --> [regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regions)      synonymised
[relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relationship) --> [relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relationships)      synonymised
[reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reload) --> [reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reloading)
[render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/render) --> [rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rendering)
[renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/renderer) --> [rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rendering)
[repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeat) --> [repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeating)
[report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/report) --> [reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reporting)
[require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/require) --> [required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/required)    synonymised
[requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requires) --> [required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/required)   is synonym
[rerender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rerender) --> [rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rendering)
[resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resolution) --> [resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resolutions)      synonymised
[restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restriction) --> [restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restrictions)    synonymised
[revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revision) --> [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revisions)      synonymised
[ria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ria) --> [rich-internet-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rich-internet-application)
[richtextediting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/richtextediting) --> [rich-text-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rich-text-editor)
[role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/role) --> [roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roles)      is synonym
[rollover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rollover) --> [rollovers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rollovers)      synonymised
[rope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rope) --> [ropes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ropes)      should stay
[routedcommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routedcommand) --> [routed-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routed-commands)   is synonym
[routedevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routedevent) --> [routed-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routed-events)   synonymised
[routedevents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routedevents) --> [routed-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routed-events)      synonymised
[router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/router) --> [routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routing)
[routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routes) --> [routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routing)
[rpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpt) --> [reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reporting)
[rtc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtc) --> [rational-team-concert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rational-team-concert)   is synonym
[rte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rte) --> [rich-text-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rich-text-editor)
[rtmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtmp) --> [rtmps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtmps)      should stay
[rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rule) --> [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rules)      is synonym
[runloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/runloop) --> [run-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/run-loop)    synonymised
[rvo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rvo) --> [return-value-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/return-value-optimization)   is synonym
[scaffold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scaffold) --> [scaffolding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scaffolding)
[scalable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scalable) --> [scalability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scalability)
[schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schedule) --> [scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheduling)
[scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheduler) --> [scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheduling)
[schtasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schtasks) --> [scheduled-tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheduled-tasks)
[scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope) --> [scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scoping)   should stay
[scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scopes) --> [scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scoping)
[scrape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrape) --> [scraper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scraper)
[scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapy) --> [scrapyd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapyd)
[screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen) --> [screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screens)      synonymised
[scriptlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scriptlet) --> [scriplets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scriplets)
[scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollbar) --> [scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollbars)    synonymised
[scroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scroller) --> [scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollbars)
[scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollview) --> [scrollviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollviewer)
[sdn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdn) --> [spring-data-neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-data-neo4j)
[secs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/secs) --> [seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seconds)
[segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/segment) --> [segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/segments)    synonymised
[select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) --> [selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selected)
[sencha-cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sencha-cmd) --> [sencha-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sencha-command)
[sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sentence) --> [sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sequences)
[sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sequence) --> [sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sequences)      synonymised
[serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serializable) --> [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialization)
[serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serializer) --> [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialization)
[sessionstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sessionstorage) --> [session-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session-storage)      synonymised
[setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setting) --> [settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings)    is synonym
[settings-bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings-bundle) --> [settings.bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings.bundle)
[sgen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sgen) --> [sgen.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sgen.exe)
[shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shadow) --> [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shadowing)    synonymised
[shadows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shadows) --> [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shadowing)   is synonym
[shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shape) --> [shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shapes)    synonymised
[share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/share) --> [shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared)
[sharp-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharp-architecture) --> [s#arp-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s%23arp-architecture)
[shellexecute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shellexecute) --> [shellexecuteex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shellexecuteex)     is synonym
[shopp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopp) --> [shopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopping)
[shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) --> [shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shortcuts)      synonymised
[showdialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/showdialog) --> [showmodaldialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/showmodaldialog)
[sid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sid) --> [sessionid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sessionid)
[signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signals) --> [signaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signaling)
[signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signature) --> [signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signatures)    synonymised
[singleinstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleinstance) --> [single-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-instance)      synonymised
[singlepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singlepage) --> [single-page-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-page-application)      is synonym
[skimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skimage) --> [scikit-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scikit-image)    is synonym
[skin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skin) --> [skins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skins)      discuss/disambiguate
[sknode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sknode) --> [sklabelnode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sklabelnode)
[slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slice) --> [splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splice)
[slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slide) --> [sliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sliders)
[slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slider) --> [sliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sliders)      synonymised
[slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slot) --> [slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slots)      synonymised
[smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smooth) --> [smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smoothing)    is synonym
[smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smtp) --> [smtps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smtps)      should stay
[som](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/som) --> [self-organizing-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-organizing-maps)
[sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sortable) --> [sortables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sortables)      is synonym
[space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space) --> [spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spaces)    should stay
[spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spawn) --> [spawning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spawning)
[specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specs) --> [specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specifications)
[speech-synthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speech-synthesis) --> [speechsynthesizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speechsynthesizer)
[spline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spline) --> [splines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splines)      synonymised
[spoof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spoof) --> [spoofing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spoofing)
[sqlite.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite.net) --> [sqlite-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite-net)
[sqlparameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameter) --> [sqlparameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlparameters)
[ssdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt) --> [sql-server-data-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-data-tools)
[ssi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssi) --> [server-side-includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-side-includes)
[stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack) --> [stacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stacked)
[state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/state) --> [states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/states)    synonymised
[static-initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-initializer) --> [static-initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-initialization)
[stem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stem) --> [stemming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stemming)
[sti](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sti) --> [single-table-inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance)
[stock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stock) --> [stocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stocks)    synonymised
[store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/store) --> [storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storage)
[strchr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strchr) --> [strrchr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strrchr)
[stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream) --> [streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/streaming)
[stretch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stretch) --> [stretched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stretched)
[strip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strip) --> [stripes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stripes)
[strophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strophe) --> [strophe.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strophe.js)
[stub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stub) --> [stubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stubs)      synonymised
[subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subclass) --> [subclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subclassing)
[subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectory) --> [subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectories)
[subdirs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirs) --> [subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectories)
[subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdomain) --> [subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdomains)
[subform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subform) --> [subforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subforms)    synonymised
[submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/submitting) --> [submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/submission)
[subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subreport) --> [subreports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subreports)    synonymised
[subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subscribe) --> [subscriber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subscriber)
[subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subscription) --> [subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subscriptions)      synonymised
[substr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substr) --> [substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substrings)
[substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substring) --> [substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substrings)
[subtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subtype) --> [subtyping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subtyping)
[subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subview) --> [subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subviews)    synonymised
[supervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/supervisor) --> [supervisord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/supervisord)
[suppress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suppress) --> [suppression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suppression)
[symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symbol) --> [symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symbols)      is synonym
[synchronisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronisation) --> [synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronization)
[synchronize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronize) --> [synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronization)
[synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronized) --> [synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronization)
[synchronizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronizing) --> [synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronization)
[syntaxhighlighter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntaxhighlighter) --> [syntax-highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting)
[sysadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sysadmin) --> [system-administration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system-administration)
[system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system) --> [systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systemd)
[systemexit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systemexit) --> [system.exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system.exit)
[systemjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systemjs) --> [system.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system.js)
[systray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systray) --> [system-tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system-tray)
[table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) --> [tablename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablename)
[tabview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabview) --> [tabbed-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabbed-view)
[target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/target) --> [targeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/targeting)    synonymised
[targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/targets) --> [targeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/targeting)   is synonym
[template-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-engine) --> [templating-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templating-engine)
[templatetag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templatetag) --> [templatetags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templatetags)    is synonym
[tesselation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tesselation) --> [tessellation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tessellation)
[tether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tether) --> [tethering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tethering)
[text-mining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-mining) --> [topic-modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topic-modeling)
[threadstatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/threadstatic) --> [thread-static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread-static)      synonymised
[throw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/throw) --> [throws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/throws)    should stay
[tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tile) --> [tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tiles)
[tiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tiled) --> [tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tiles)
[tm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tm) --> [topic-modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topic-modeling)
[tmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tmp) --> [temp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temp)
[todo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/todo) --> [todos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/todos)
[toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toolbar) --> [toolbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toolbars)    synonymised
[topicmodels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topicmodels) --> [topic-modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topic-modeling)
[tph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tph) --> [table-per-hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-per-hierarchy)
[track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/track) --> [tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tracking)
[trail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trail) --> [trailing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trailing)
[transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transactions) --> [transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transactional)
[transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition) --> [transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transitions)      synonymised
[translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translate) --> [translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/translation)
[transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transparent) --> [transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transparency)
[treemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/treemap) --> [treemaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/treemaps)    synonymised
[treenode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/treenode) --> [tree-nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree-nodes)     synonymised
[trend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trend) --> [trending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trending)
[triples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triples) --> [triplet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triplet)
[truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncate) --> [truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/truncated)
[trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trust) --> [trusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trusted)
[tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tunnel) --> [tunneling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tunneling)
[turnjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turnjs) --> [turn.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turn.js)
[tv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tv) --> [television](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/television)
[tvp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tvp) --> [table-valued-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-valued-parameters)     is synonym
[twist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twist) --> [twisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twisted)
[typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeahead) --> [typeahead.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeahead.js)      synonymised
[typeconverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeconverter) --> [type-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-conversion)
[typeconverting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeconverting) --> [type-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-conversion)      is synonym
[typedarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typedarray) --> [typed-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typed-arrays)     is synonym
[typelib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typelib) --> [type-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-library)
[typelibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typelibrary) --> [type-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-library)    synonymised
[uart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uart) --> [usart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usart)
[udf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udf) --> [user-defined-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-defined-functions)      is synonym
[uia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uia) --> [ui-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui-automation)
[uibutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uibutton) --> [uibarbuttonitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uibarbuttonitem)
[uid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uid) --> [userid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/userid)
[uisearchbardisplaycontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uisearchbardisplaycontrol) --> [uisearchdisplaycontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uisearchdisplaycontroller)
[umount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/umount) --> [unmount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unmount)
[unbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unbox) --> [unboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unboxing)
[uncheck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uncheck) --> [unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unchecked)
[underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscores) --> [underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underscore.js)
[uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstall) --> [uninstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstaller)
[union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/union) --> [unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unions)    should stay
[upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/upload) --> [uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uploading)
[urlrewriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlrewriter) --> [urlrewriting.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlrewriting.net)    is synonym
[urlrewriter.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlrewriter.net) --> [urlrewriting.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlrewriting.net)
[utf-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/utf-16) --> [utf-16le](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/utf-16le)
[util](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/util) --> [utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/utils)
[v4l](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/v4l) --> [video4linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video4linux)
[va-arg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/va-arg) --> [varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/varargs)      is synonym
[validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validation) --> [validating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validating)
[vao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vao) --> [vertex-array-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vertex-array-object)
[var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/var) --> [variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variables)
[variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variant) --> [variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variants)    synonymised
[variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variation) --> [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variations)    is synonym
[vendor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vendor) --> [vendors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vendors)      synonymised
[version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version) --> [versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versioning)      synonymised
[versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versions) --> [versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/versioning)     is synonym
[vfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vfs) --> [virtualfilesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualfilesystem)
[vhosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhosts) --> [virtual-hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-hosts)
[view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/view) --> [views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/views)      synonymised
[viewhelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewhelper) --> [view-helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/view-helpers)     is synonym
[virtualhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualhost) --> [virtual-hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-hosts)   synonymised
[visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visitor) --> [visitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visitors)    discuss/disambiguate
[volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/volume) --> [volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/volumes)      discuss/disambiguate
[voxel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/voxel) --> [voxels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/voxels)    synonymised
[vr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vr) --> [virtual-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality)      is synonym
[vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode) --> [visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code)   is synonym
[vsm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsm) --> [visualstatemanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualstatemanager)
[vspackage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vspackage) --> [visual-studio-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-package)
[vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs) --> [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js)    is synonym
[vxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vxml) --> [voicexml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/voicexml)
[wdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wdk) --> [winddk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winddk)
[web-config-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-config-transform) --> [web.config-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web.config-transform)
[webcontent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webcontent) --> [web-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-content)      synonymised
[webdeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdeploy) --> [web-deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-deployment)
[webmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webmethod) --> [webmethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webmethods)    discuss/disambiguate
[webservice-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webservice-client) --> [webservices-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webservices-client)    synonymised
[webtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webtest) --> [web-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-testing)
[webusercontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webusercontrol) --> [web-user-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-user-controls)    synonymised
[webusercontrols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webusercontrols) --> [web-user-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-user-controls)   synonymised
[weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weight) --> [weighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weighting)
[weighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weighted) --> [weighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weighting)
[winapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapp) --> [windows-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-applications)
[window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window) --> [windowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowing)
[window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window.open) --> [window.opener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window.opener)
[windowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowed) --> [windowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowing)
[window-messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window-messages) --> [windows-messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-messages)
[windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) --> [windowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowing)   should stay
[window-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window-server) --> [windows-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server)
[windowsformhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsformhost) --> [windows-forms-host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms-host)      is synonym
[windowsformshost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsformshost) --> [windows-forms-host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms-host)     synonymised
[wmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wmp) --> [windows-media-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-media-player)
[word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) --> [words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/words)      synonymised
[word-boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-boundary) --> [word-boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-boundaries)
[workflowservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workflowservice) --> [workflow-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workflow-services)   synonymised
[wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap) --> [wraps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wraps)      synonymised
[writablebitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writablebitmap) --> [writeablebitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writeablebitmap)
[writer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writer) --> [writers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writers)      synonymised
[wse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wse) --> [ws-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ws-security)
[x509](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x509) --> [x509certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x509certificate)
[xamarin.forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms) --> [xamarin-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin-forms)
[xmldoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmldoc) --> [xml-documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-documentation)
[xml-rpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-rpc) --> [xmlrpclib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlrpclib)
[xuggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xuggle) --> [xuggler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xuggler)
[xunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xunit) --> [xunit.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xunit.net)
[zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zone) --> [zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zones)      synonymised

(Status added from [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags) or for 'is synonym' based on this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/868741/tag-synonyms-mapped) courtesy of [@modelbuilder42](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/28134/modelbuilder42) but *not* fully up to date  - eg  [alwaysontop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alwaysontop) *nor*  fully accurate/comprehensive - eg [dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos) and [denial-of-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/denial-of-service) / [ddos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ddos)).

**Note**

- If some of them are not right, feel free to edit it or ask me to do it;
- If you find more synonyms which are not in the list and have not enough reputation propose it in Stack Overflow, also feel free to add them in this list;
- If you think the pairs are right and have the reputation to propose such tag synonyms, please help me propose them.

Thanks and hope Stack Overflow can be better!

Comment: Awesome list, but the directionality of some synonyms is questionable. At work now, will propose changes when I get home.

Comment: Note that some of these tags probably need to be burninated and not synonymised. Also note [tag:paginate]/[tag:paginator]/[tag:pagination] should probably all be the same thing.

Comment: I find many questionable tags, obvious typos, and suggestions from a clear tag to an ambiguous one (oracle-service-bus to osb, really?). Most of those should just be deleted rather than synonymized.

Comment: I believe `jil` is simply a type of json serializer, might still make sense to have both. `window-messages` I believe is different from `windows-messages`, since one implies an OS and the other doesn't. I suppose it depends on how they are used in practice. Some of the abbreviations are a bit ridiculous imo.

Comment: Answer score of 5 is indeed realy strict. Just curious who has the required score of any and is activly participating on meta. And the people who are not on meta maybe don't even know about tag synonyms. No wonder we have such a huge list ;)

Comment: Would you like to list your paper on the [curated list of academic papers using Stack Exchange data](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data)?

Comment: And here I thought [tag:meta-tags] were a no-no!

Comment: @code11 `jil` can also be the "Job Information Language", a scripting language for Autosys jobs

Comment: now all we need is a way to show which ones are pending, done, or rejected.

Comment: `ipcs` is a specific command that you can use to inspect usage of SysV IPC on your system. `ipc` is a huge category. `cc` just means C compiler, not cross-compiler. `cleditor` and `ckeditor` are, as far as I can tell, competitors.

Comment: Honest question about protocol: Don't each of these deserve their own meta post where we can figure out how the synonym should work, if at all? As I, Patrick Haugh and Wumpus pointed out, its not a straight shot on a fair number of these, and the directionality is dodgy at best on others.

Comment: `package-capture` sounds like a general topic, while `pcap` is a specific library. `square-root` - general topic, `sqrt` - name of a function, `datediff` - specific  function...

Comment: `qsort` is a specific function which, at least in case of the C language, often **does not use `quicksort`**.

Comment: @NisseEngström Thanks for the reminding, have removed them.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Thanks for the suggestion, have removed them.

Comment: `va-arg` is exclusive to `c`, `c++` and `objective-c` while `varargs` is also used with several other languages. I don't know if it should be synonymized, burninated or given its own tag description.

Comment: `mpchart` -> `mpandroidchart` has been done manually. see [this retag request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327650/the-number-of-mistakenly-tagged-questions-is-off-the-mpchart)

Comment: angular and angularjs are nominally different technologies. I dispute that set of synonyms. Also flush/fflush and curl/libcurl.

Answer (score 23):

Just to make this huge task a little bit easier, here is a list with the URL's to the tag. If you have proposed a change, please edit this answer to remove the tag:

The idea is to make the left tag a synonym of the right tag(s). But please review carefully. Something like `rich-text-editor` could be better than `rte`

- [ajax-forms (28)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax-forms) --> [ajaxform (402)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxform)
- [formsauthentication (110)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formsauthentication) --> [form-authentication (190)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-authentication) or [forms-authentication (3006)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms-authentication)
- [menu-items (42)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu-items) --> [menuitem (1918)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menuitem)
- [jarsign (10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jarsign) --> [jar-signing (182)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jar-signing)
- [tabbed-view (42)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabbed-view) --> [tabview (336)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabview)
- [windowsformhost (27)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsformhost) --> [windowsformshost (125)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsformshost)
- [equality-operator (28)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality-operator) --> [equals-operator (132)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals-operator)
- [codesign (357)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codesign) --> [code-signing (1710)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-signing)
- [log-files (30)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log-files) --> [logfiles (199)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logfiles)
- [clisp (309)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clisp) --> [common-lisp (3741)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common-lisp)
- [data-formats (45)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-formats) --> [dataformat (143)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataformat)
- [decimal-format (16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decimal-format) --> [decimalformat (355)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decimalformat)
- [googlesigninaccount (38)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlesigninaccount) --> [google-account (277)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-account)
- [dynamic-html (83)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-html) --> [dhtml (728)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dhtml)
- [checklistbox (87)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checklistbox) --> [checkedlistbox (349)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checkedlistbox)
- [subdirectories (288)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectories) --> [subdirectory (610)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectory)
- [access-point (113)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-point) --> [apn (141)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apn)
- [qwebkit (136)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qwebkit) --> [qtwebkit (622)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtwebkit)
- [er-diagram (36)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/er-diagram) --> [erd (576)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erd)
- [writablebitmap (46)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writablebitmap) --> [writeablebitmap (255)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writeablebitmap)
- [square-root (218)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/square-root) --> [sqrt (227)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqrt)
- [event-listener (97)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listener) --> [eventlistener (740)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventlistener)
- [referer (168)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/referer) --> [referrer (457)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/referrer)
- [keyevent (850)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyevent) --> [keyboard-events (1313)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-events)
- [packet-capture (465)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packet-capture) --> [pcap (886)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcap)
- [oracle-service-bus (66)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-service-bus) --> [osb (332)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osb)
- [rich-internet-application (117)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rich-internet-application) --> [ria (860)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ria)
- [double-buffering (113)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-buffering) --> [doublebuffered (176)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doublebuffered)
- [system-administration (258)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system-administration) --> [sysadmin (412)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sysadmin)
- [multiple-processes (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-processes) --> [multiprocess (206)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiprocess)
- [datetime-parsing (81)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime-parsing) --> [date-parsing (186)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-parsing)
- [pdfjs (121)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdfjs) --> [pdf.js (420)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf.js)
- [entity-sql (56)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-sql) --> [esql (120)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql)
- [alassetlibrary (30)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alassetlibrary) --> [alassetslibrary (618)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alassetslibrary)
- [multiple-value (98)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-value) --> [multivalue (217)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multivalue)
- [json-web-token (173)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-web-token) --> [jwt (2574)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jwt)
- [jeasyui (63)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jeasyui) --> [jquery-easyui (333)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-easyui)
- [args (441)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/args) --> [arguments (6288)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arguments)
- [typelibrary (17)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typelibrary) --> [type-library (161)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-library)
- [voicexml (108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/voicexml) --> [vxml (140)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vxml)
- [routedevent (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routedevent) --> [routed-events (178)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routed-events)
- [file-read (281)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-read) --> [filereader (1605)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filereader)
- [xmldom (198)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmldom) --> [xmldocument (947)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmldocument)
- [libwww-perl (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libwww-perl) --> [lwp (307)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lwp)
- [bll (106)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bll) --> [business-logic-layer (198)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/business-logic-layer)
- [filebrowse (15)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filebrowse) --> [file-browser (171)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-browser)
- [settings-bundle (21)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings-bundle) --> [settings.bundle (290)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings.bundle)
- [collaborative (34)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collaborative) --> [collaboration (424)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collaboration)
- [googlesigninapi (50)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlesigninapi) --> [google-signin (1030)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-signin)
- [gcal (48)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcal) --> [google-calendar (3637)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar)
- [visual-studio-package (32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-package) --> [vspackage (327)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vspackage)
- [delimited (134)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delimited) --> [delimiter (1649)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delimiter)
- [audiostreamer (54)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audiostreamer) --> [audio-streaming (1659)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-streaming)
- [sql-server-data-tools (108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-data-tools) --> [ssdt (915)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt)
- [appsettings (365)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appsettings) --> [application-settings (651)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-settings)
- [initializing (66)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initializing) --> [initialization (7153)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initialization)
- [fulltext-index (70)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fulltext-index) --> [full-text-indexing (388)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/full-text-indexing)
- [date-difference (147)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-difference) --> [datediff (896)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datediff)
- [angularjs-google-maps (35)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-google-maps) --> [angular-google-maps (309)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-google-maps)
- [event-listeners (242)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listeners) --> [eventlistener (740)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventlistener)
- [self-organizing-maps (84)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-organizing-maps) --> [som (118)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/som)
- [cardio (24)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cardio) --> [card.io (197)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/card.io)
- [numberformatter (54)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numberformatter) --> [number-formatting (1499)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/number-formatting)
- [beizer (17)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beizer) --> [bezier (526)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bezier)
- [nested-query (102)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-query) --> [nested-queries (260)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-queries)
- [database-link (71)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-link) --> [dblink (255)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dblink)
- [node-streams (46)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-streams) --> [node.js-stream (137)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js-stream)
- [data-cleansing (200)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-cleansing) --> [data-cleaning (264)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-cleaning)
- [static-initializer (66)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-initializer) --> [static-initialization (190)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-initialization)
- [sqlite.net (69)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite.net) --> [sqlite-net (285)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite-net)
- [web-user-controls (108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-user-controls) --> [webusercontrol (247)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webusercontrol)
- [cc (175)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cc) --> [cross-compiling (2486)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-compiling)
- [fpc (1050)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fpc) --> [freepascal (1050)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freepascal)
- [data-transfer-objects (105)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-transfer-objects) --> [dto (982)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dto)
- [event-viewer (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-viewer) --> [eventviewer (176)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventviewer)
- [adobe-native-extensions (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-native-extensions) --> [ane (132)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ane)
- [builtin (116)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/builtin) --> [built-in (472)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in)
- [visual-studio-code (2888)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) --> [vscode (2888)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode)
- [sharp-architecture (75)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharp-architecture) --> [s#arp-architecture (62)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s#arp-architecture)
- [store (2273)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/store) --> [storage (3741)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storage)
- [transparent (1523)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transparent) --> [transparency (2775)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transparency)
- [ipcs (22)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipcs) --> [inter-process-communicat (3222)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inter-process-communicat)
- [kernel-extension (34)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel-extension) --> [kext (196)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kext)
- [angularjs-ng-if (36)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-if) --> [angular-ng-if (335)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-if)
- [workflow-services (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workflow-services) --> [workflowservice (147)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workflowservice)
- [last-insert-id (125)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/last-insert-id) --> [lastinsertid (134)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lastinsertid)
- [webdeploy (857)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdeploy) --> [web-deployment (2261)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-deployment)
- [pop-up (170)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop-up) --> [popup (7721)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popup)
- [meteor-useraccounts (20)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor-useraccounts) --> [meteor-accounts (586)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor-accounts)
- [yo (165)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yo) --> [yeoman (2172)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yeoman)
- [equivalence (122)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equivalence) --> [equivalent (276)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equivalent)
- [multifile (56)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multifile) --> [multiple-files (338)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-files)
- [angularjs-templates (69)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-templates) --> [angular-template (151)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-template)
- [web-config-transform (151)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-config-transform) --> [web.config-transform (190)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web.config-transform)
- [webusercontrols (21)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webusercontrols) --> [web-user-controls (108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-user-controls)
- [boost.build (19)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost.build) --> [boost-build (112)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-build)
- [syntaxhighlighter (138)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntaxhighlighter) --> [syntax-highlighting (2548)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting)
- [rdebug (15)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdebug) --> [ruby-debug (146)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-debug)
- [cakephp-model (59)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-model) --> [cakephp-appmodel (440)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-appmodel)
- [sti (322)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sti) --> [single-table-inheritance (497)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance)
- [lostfocus (75)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lostfocus) --> [lost-focus (122)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lost-focus)
- [hls (561)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hls) --> [http-live-streaming (794)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-live-streaming)
- [intermediate-language (93)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intermediate-language) --> [il (1183)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/il)
- [capture-group (84)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture-group) --> [capturing-group (123)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capturing-group)
- [tree-nodes (45)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree-nodes) --> [treenode (500)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/treenode)
- [formatted (63)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formatted) --> [formatter (504)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formatter)
- [persistent (587)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistent) --> [persistence (3996)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistence)
- [portable-executable (180)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/portable-executable) --> [pe (498)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pe)
- [ivar (133)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ivar) --> [instance-variables (1071)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instance-variables)
- [router (1645)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/router) --> [routes (9863)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routes)
- [webservices-client (237)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webservices-client) --> [webservice-client (944)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webservice-client)
- [multiple-file-upload (97)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-file-upload) --> [multifile-uploader (216)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multifile-uploader)
- [dynamic-queries (85)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-queries) --> [dynamicquery (166)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamicquery)
- [va-arg (100)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/va-arg) --> [varargs (780)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/varargs)
- [udf (514)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udf) --> [user-defined-functions (1834)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-defined-functions)
- [end-of-line (90)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/end-of-line) --> [eol (248)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eol)
- [kvc (161)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kvc) --> [key-value-coding (348)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key-value-coding)
- [alwaysontop (24)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alwaysontop) --> [always-on-top (109)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/always-on-top)
- [window-server (54)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window-server) --> [windows-server (539)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server)
- [sencha-command (25)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sencha-command) --> [sencha-cmd (380)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sencha-cmd)
- [location-based-service (40)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/location-based-service) --> [location-services (189)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/location-services)
- [jtemplates (44)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jtemplates) --> [jquery-templates (744)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-templates)
- [mq (651)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mq) --> [message-queue (2470)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/message-queue)
- [google-authenticator (94)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-authenticator) --> [google-authentication (649)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-authentication)
- [azuread (199)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azuread) --> [azure-active-directory (1589)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-active-directory)
- [fsm (335)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fsm) --> [finite-state-machine (341)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finite-state-machine)
- [quality-center (177)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quality-center) --> [qc (228)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc)
- [dimension-reduction (16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimension-reduction) --> [dimensionality-reduction (139)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimensionality-reduction)
- [uia (25)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uia) --> [ui-automation (1684)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui-automation)
- [cleditor (67)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cleditor) --> [ckeditor (6559)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ckeditor)
- [access-point-name (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-point-name) --> [apn (141)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apn)
- [ane (132)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ane) --> [air-native-extension (281)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/air-native-extension)
- [interpreted (33)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpreted) --> [interpreter (1481)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)
- [abtest (35)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abtest) --> [ab-testing (249)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ab-testing)
- [typedarray (30)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typedarray) --> [typed-arrays (172)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typed-arrays)
- [deeplink (60)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deeplink) --> [deep-linking (1079)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-linking)
- [elastic-map-reduce (444)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elastic-map-reduce) --> [emr (884)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emr)
- [mongo-java (231)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo-java) --> [mongodb-java (778)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-java)
- [edt (34)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edt) --> [event-dispatch-thread (670)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread)
- [collapsable (141)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapsable) --> [collapse (1109)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapse)
- [singlepage (203)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singlepage) --> [single-page-application (2375)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-page-application)
- [key-events (194)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key-events) --> [keyevent (850)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyevent)
- [application-bar (100)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-bar) --> [appbar (231)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appbar)
- [blobstorage (107)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blobstorage) --> [blobstore (797)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blobstore)
- [multipleselection (212)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multipleselection) --> [multiple-select (262)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-select)
- [analog-digital-converter (61)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/analog-digital-converter) --> [adc (195)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adc)
- [dynamic-usercontrols (63)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-usercontrols) --> [dynamic-controls (287)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-controls)
- [dynamicform (91)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamicform) --> [dynamic-forms (162)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-forms)
- [google-closure-libraries (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-closure-libraries) --> [google-closure-library (324)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-closure-library)
- [poptoviewcontroller (66)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poptoviewcontroller) --> [popviewcontroller (121)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popviewcontroller)
- [btle (51)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/btle) --> [bluetooth-lowenergy (3949)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-lowenergy)
- [output-caching (34)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/output-caching) --> [outputcache (629)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outputcache)
- [enumerator (285)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enumerator) --> [enumeration (1349)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enumeration)
- [angular-filters (573)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-filters) --> [angularjs-filter (1025)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-filter)
- [boost-jam (7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-jam) --> [bjam (196)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bjam)
- [change-data-capture (93)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/change-data-capture) --> [cdc (220)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdc)
- [info-plist (46)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/info-plist) --> [info.plist (418)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/info.plist)
- [multiple-users (78)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-users) --> [multi-user (248)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-user)
- [process-control (32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/process-control) --> [pcntl (136)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcntl)
- [auto-rotation (114)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-rotation) --> [autorotate (399)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autorotate)
- [global-assembly-cache (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/global-assembly-cache) --> [gac (929)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gac)
- [audiorecord (315)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audiorecord) --> [audio-recording (1477)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording)
- [role-based-access-control (35)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/role-based-access-control) --> [rbac (365)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rbac)
- [rational-team-concert (72)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rational-team-concert) --> [rtc (394)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtc)
- [opendocument (69)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opendocument) --> [odt (135)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odt)
- [dbproj (29)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbproj) --> [database-project (494)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-project)
- [angularjs-http (300)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-http) --> [angular-http (438)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-http)
- [angular-module (74)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-module) --> [angularjs-module (163)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-module)
- [multi-monitor (104)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-monitor) --> [multiple-monitors (330)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors)
- [word-boundaries (24)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-boundaries) --> [word-boundary (113)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-boundary)
- [listview-adapter (112)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview-adapter) --> [listadapter (899)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listadapter)
- [topic-modeling (296)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topic-modeling) --> [tm (654)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tm)
- [topicmodels (27)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topicmodels) --> [topic-modeling (296)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topic-modeling)
- [administrator (480)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administrator) --> [administration (536)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administration)
- [transactional (563)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transactional) --> [transactions (10809)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transactions)
- [television (34)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/television) --> [tv (295)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tv)
- [qsort (374)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qsort) --> [quicksort (1770)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quicksort)
- [jexcelapi (181)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jexcelapi) --> [jxl (392)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jxl)
- [angularjs-resource (272)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-resource) --> [angular-resource (722)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-resource)
- [builtins (51)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/builtins) --> [built-in (472)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in)
- [pch (95)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pch) --> [precompiled-headers (293)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precompiled-headers)
- [filehandle (290)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filehandle) --> [file-handling (1173)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-handling)
- [virtual-hosts (224)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-hosts) --> [virtualhost (2101)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualhost)
- [azure-management-api (77)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-management-api) --> [azure-api-management (174)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-api-management)
- [advertisement (246)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advertisement) --> [ads (1653)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ads)
- [wmp (177)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wmp) --> [windows-media-player (325)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-media-player)
- [over-the-air (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/over-the-air) --> [ota (262)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ota)
- [lazyload (54)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lazyload) --> [lazy-loading (3188)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lazy-loading)
- [django-caching (37)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-caching) --> [django-cache (144)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-cache)
- [dbconnection (126)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbconnection) --> [database-connection (4763)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-connection)
- [speechsynthesizer (45)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speechsynthesizer) --> [speech-synthesis (249)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speech-synthesis)
- [disassembly (382)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disassembly) --> [disassembling (508)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disassembling)
- [multiple-languages (111)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-languages) --> [multilanguage (960)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilanguage)
- [hdd (115)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdd) --> [hard-drive (576)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive)
- [emulation (364)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulation) --> [emulator (2846)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulator)
- [xamarin-forms (6184)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin-forms) --> [xamarin.forms (6184)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms)
- [options-menu (113)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options-menu) --> [optionmenu (227)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optionmenu)
- [apn (141)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apn) --> [apple-push-notifications (5621)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications)
- [angularjs-bootstrap (95)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-bootstrap) --> [angular-bootstrap (366)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-bootstrap)
- [angular-controller (240)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-controller) --> [angularjs-controller (1094)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-controller)
- [mtm (141)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mtm) --> [microsoft-test-manager (334)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-test-manager)
- [systray (81)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systray) --> [system-tray (512)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system-tray)
- [uisearchbardisplaycontrol (72)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uisearchbardisplaycontrol) --> [uisearchdisplaycontroller (824)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uisearchdisplaycontroller)
- [dih (136)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dih) --> [dataimporthandler (333)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataimporthandler)
- [viewhelper (58)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewhelper) --> [view-helpers (358)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/view-helpers)
- [mpchart (63)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpchart) --> [mpandroidchart (893)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpandroidchart)
- [adaptor (55)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adaptor) --> [adapter (3504)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adapter)
- [embedded-ruby (54)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-ruby) --> [erb (2013)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erb)
- [formhelper (139)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formhelper) --> [form-helpers (284)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-helpers)
- [gwt-platform (244)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt-platform) --> [gwtp (343)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwtp)
- [templating-engine (67)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templating-engine) --> [template-engine (1457)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-engine)
- [hiddenfield (123)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hiddenfield) --> [hidden-field (737)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-field)
- [angularjs-ng-model (359)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-model) --> [angular-ngmodel (1031)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ngmodel)
- [android-internet (198)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-internet) --> [android-intent (24007)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent)
- [embedded-javascript (41)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-javascript) --> [ejs (1442)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ejs)
- [asp.net-compiler (13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-compiler) --> [aspnet-compiler (132)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspnet-compiler)
- [pyunit (138)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyunit) --> [python-unittest (788)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-unittest)
- [tvp (62)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tvp) --> [table-valued-parameters (208)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-valued-parameters)
- [accesscontrolservice (33)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accesscontrolservice) --> [acs (373)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acs)
- [skimage (108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skimage) --> [scikit-image (315)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scikit-image)
- [windows-forms-host (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms-host) --> [windowsformshost (125)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsformshost)
- [sessionstorage (110)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sessionstorage) --> [session-storage (306)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session-storage)
- [validating (109)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validating) --> [validation (46826)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validation)
- [window-messages (59)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window-messages) --> [windows-messages (235)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-messages)
- [human-computer-interface (42)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/human-computer-interface) --> [hci (111)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hci)
- [customizing (74)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customizing) --> [customization (3138)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customization)
- [mouse-listeners (138)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouse-listeners) --> [mouselistener (936)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouselistener)
- [routedevents (15)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routedevents) --> [routed-events (178)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routed-events)
- [server-side-includes (215)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-side-includes) --> [ssi (311)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssi)
- [form-authentication (190)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-authentication) --> [forms-authentication (3006)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms-authentication)
- [vuejs (322)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs) --> [vue.js (3427)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js)
- [routedcommand (21)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routedcommand) --> [routed-commands (142)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routed-commands)
- [multiple-select (262)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-select) --> [multi-select (1256)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-select)
- [itemsource (85)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itemsource) --> [itemssource (311)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itemssource)
- [virtualfilesystem (41)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualfilesystem) --> [vfs (214)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vfs)
- [backbone.js-collections (105)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone.js-collections) --> [backbone-collections (392)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone-collections)
- [covariant (51)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/covariant) --> [covariance (1161)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/covariance)
- [domready (108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/domready) --> [document-ready (605)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/document-ready)
- [single-instance (44)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-instance) --> [singleinstance (152)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleinstance)
- [applicationdomain (63)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applicationdomain) --> [appdomain (1206)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appdomain)
- [fab (214)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab) --> [floating-action-button (649)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-action-button)
- [ajaxuploader (16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxuploader) --> [ajax-upload (106)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax-upload)
- [data-storage (370)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-storage) --> [datastore (480)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datastore)
- [django-tests (126)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-tests) --> [django-testing (568)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-testing)
- [modified-preorder-tree-t (19)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modified-preorder-tree-t) --> [mptt (114)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mptt)
- [contenttype (78)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contenttype) --> [content-type (1709)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-type)
- [er-diagrams (93)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/er-diagrams) --> [erd (576)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erd)
- [bulkloader (164)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bulkloader) --> [bulk-load (194)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bulk-load)
- [drop-shadow (29)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drop-shadow) --> [dropshadow (237)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropshadow)
- [virtual-hosts (224)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-hosts) --> [vhosts (700)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhosts)
- [rpt (32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpt) --> [report (5198)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/report)
- [io-completion-ports (58)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io-completion-ports) --> [iocp (261)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iocp)
- [eventreceiver (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventreceiver) --> [event-receiver (126)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-receiver)
- [automaton (77)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automaton) --> [automata (363)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automata)
- [maximization (34)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maximization) --> [minimization (214)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minimization)
- [django-mailer (33)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-mailer) --> [django-email (114)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-email)
- [hextiles (21)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hextiles) --> [hexagonal-tiles (121)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hexagonal-tiles)
- [complex-event-processing (61)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complex-event-processing) --> [cep (371)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep)
- [event-triggers (63)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-triggers) --> [eventtrigger (441)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventtrigger)
- [angular-routing (927)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-routing) --> [angularjs-routing (1198)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-routing)
- [django-tagging (61)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-tagging) --> [django-taggit (141)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-taggit)
- [minmax (105)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minmax) --> [minimax (407)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minimax)
- [winddk (161)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winddk) --> [wdk (348)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wdk)
- [distributed-cache (135)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distributed-cache) --> [distributed-caching (301)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distributed-caching)
- [charts.js (125)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/charts.js) --> [chart.js (2253)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chart.js)
- [rte (212)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rte) --> [rich-text-editor (665)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rich-text-editor)
- [disassembler (120)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disassembler) --> [disassembly (382)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disassembly)
- [left-recursion (117)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/left-recursion) --> [lr (125)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lr)
- [synchronisation (77)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronisation) --> [synchronization (9075)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronization)
- [xmldoc (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmldoc) --> [xml-documentation (244)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-documentation)
- [angular-directive (878)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-directive) --> [angularjs-directive (15481)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-directive)
- [pdfviewer (67)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdfviewer) --> [pdf-viewer (147)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf-viewer)
- [multi-database (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-database) --> [multiple-databases (420)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-databases)
- [keystonejs (340)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystonejs) --> [keystone.js (340)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystone.js)
- [refcounting (39)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refcounting) --> [reference-counting (297)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reference-counting)
- [integration-tests (78)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration-tests) --> [integration-testing (3498)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration-testing)
- [metatag (65)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metatag) --> [meta-tags (1616)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags)
- [osk (51)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osk) --> [on-screen-keyboard (121)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/on-screen-keyboard)
- [virtual-reality (153)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality) --> [vr (494)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vr)
- [richtextediting (36)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/richtextediting) --> [rte (212)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rte)
- [tm (654)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tm) --> [text-mining (1238)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-mining)
- [data-members (58)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-members) --> [datamember (149)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datamember)
- [linux-containers (93)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-containers) --> [lxc (382)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lxc)
- [performance-monitor (37)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance-monitor) --> [perfmon (241)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perfmon)
- [bit-masks (45)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-masks) --> [bitmask (441)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitmask)
- [normalizing (26)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalizing) --> [normalization (2134)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalization)
- [winapp (70)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapp) --> [windows-applications (942)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-applications)
- [facebook-authorization (38)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-authorization) --> [facebook-authentication (603)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-authentication)
- [database-connectivity (68)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-connectivity) --> [database-connection (4763)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-connection)
- [rr (27)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rr) --> [rspec-rails (1506)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rspec-rails)
- [powermanager (81)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powermanager) --> [power-management (413)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/power-management)
- [log-files (30)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log-files) --> [logfile (334)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logfile)
- [tmp (204)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tmp) --> [temp (357)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temp)
- [multiple-projects (113)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-projects) --> [multi-project (204)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-project)
- [fso (69)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fso) --> [filesystemobject (209)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filesystemobject)
- [ios-extensions (219)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-extensions) --> [ios-app-extension (584)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-app-extension)
- [scriplets (78)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scriplets) --> [scriptlet (263)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scriptlet)
- [gunzip (105)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gunzip) --> [gz (230)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gz)
- [webtest (229)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webtest) --> [web-testing (328)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-testing)
- [evaluator (40)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluator) --> [evaluation (715)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluation)
- [ratelimit (41)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratelimit) --> [rate-limiting (245)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rate-limiting)
- [coords (41)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coords) --> [coordinates (3889)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coordinates)
- [http-request (383)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-request) --> [httprequest (4396)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httprequest)
- [communicate (97)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/communicate) --> [communication (1953)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/communication)
- [multi-table (95)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-table) --> [multiple-tables (658)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-tables)
- [application-data (43)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-data) --> [appdata (202)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appdata)
- [interaction (445)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interaction) --> [interactive (1004)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interactive)
- [vertex-array-object (41)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vertex-array-object) --> [vao (144)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vao)
- [migrating (66)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrating) --> [migration (6046)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration)
- [custom-validators (169)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-validators) --> [customvalidator (381)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customvalidator)
- [rdms (65)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdms) --> [rdbms (1623)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdbms)
- [content-delivery-network (30)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-delivery-network) --> [cdn (1778)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdn)
- [mvcminiprofiler (14)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvcminiprofiler) --> [mvc-mini-profiler (362)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc-mini-profiler)
- [schtasks (71)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schtasks) --> [scheduled-tasks (4164)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheduled-tasks)
- [jil (24)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jil) --> [jsonserializer (252)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonserializer)
- [paginator (154)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginator) --> [paginate (208)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginate)
- [paginator (154)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginator) --> [pagination (10865)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination)
- [mongodb-shell (54)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-shell) --> [mongo-shell (212)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo-shell)
- [command (6621)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command) --> [cmd (13725)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd)
- [typelib (95)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typelib) --> [type-library (161)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-library)
- [dfs (388)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dfs) --> [depth-first-search (837)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depth-first-search)
- [tph (59)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tph) --> [table-per-hierarchy (107)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-per-hierarchy)

Here's some c# code you can run in LINQPad. You'll need to update the `list` variable with the list from the OP:

```c#
var list = @"";
var pairs = list.Split(new char[] { '\r','\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var client = new WebClient();
var start = "<div class=\"summarycount al\">";
var startLength = start.Length;
var end = "</div>";
var output = new StringBuilder("<ul>\n");
Func<string, int> getCount = (string tag) => {
  var html = client.DownloadString("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/" + tag.Trim());
  var startIndex = html.IndexOf(start);
  var endIndex = html.IndexOf(end, startIndex);
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  return int.Parse(html.Substring(startIndex + startLength, endIndex - startIndex - startLength).Dump(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
};
foreach (var pair in pairs) {
  var tags = pair.Split(new string[] { " --> " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
  var counts = new int[] { getCount(tags[0]), getCount(tags[1]) };
  output.AppendFormat("<li><a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/{0}\">{0} ({1})</a> --&gt; <a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/{2}\">{2} ({3})</a></li>\n", tags[0], counts[0], tags[1], counts[1]);
}
output.AppendLine("</ul>");
output.ToString().Dump();
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what I'm supposed to do to this list. For instance, is the hyperlinked tag the proposed target or is the other side? I'd rather have `http-request` than `httprequest` for instance. as I find it easier to read, but I'd rather have `rich-text-editor` than `rte` but they're flipped in the list.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, I think this sould be done on a case by case base. Generaly this list is meant to make the left part a synonym to the right part.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Do you have a script that generated this post, or did you do it by hand?

Comment: In general, I believe the list should be adjusted to prefer inter-word hyphenation (e.g.: "event-triggers (63) --> eventtrigger (441)" should swapped) and non-acronym tags (e.g.: "vertex-array-object (41) --> vao (144)" should be swapped) except where the target (right-hand side) is considered industry standard. (The intent is readability so which ever way is appropriate; I may have confused what `-->` indicates.)

Comment: @JF Crap, I did have a LINQPad script, but it's gone now. Basically, I just took the list from the OP, split into rows, split each row on " --> ", called "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/" + leftHandTag, parsed out the count (using regex of course :)), then called "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/" + rightHandTag and parsed the count out of that, then pushed it all into HTML. I can probably recreate pretty quick. There's likely a way of doing it with the API, but I'm lazy.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan [status-I'm-recreating-it-in-js]

Comment: @JF Feel free to replace if you get it working in JS :).

Comment: Fair enough. But readability trumps length, at least for human consumption. No trees were harmed in the making of this answer. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for adding the numbers to @Christian Gollhardt, but that list is still too large too be processed. I will break it down into a few groups:

#### Less instances of the proposed target

Move anything up here if you want to suggest the less common used to be become the canonical tag name.

- [sharp-architecture (75)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharp-architecture) ⇒ [s#arp-architecture (62)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s#arp-architecture) (this was in the original list, dunno why)

#### Only difference in the more popular (proposed target) having more punctuation

This is usually a good thing.

- [pdfjs (121)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdfjs) ⇒ [pdf.js (420)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf.js)
- <s>[typelibrary (17)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typelibrary) ⇒ [type-library (161)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-library)</s>
- [typelib (95)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typelib) ⇒ [type-library (161)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-library)
- [cardio (24)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cardio) ⇒ [card.io (197)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/card.io)
- [builtin (116)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/builtin) ⇒ [built-in (472)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in)
- [webusercontrols (21)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webusercontrols) ⇒ [web-user-controls (108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-user-controls)
- [lostfocus (75)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lostfocus) ⇒ [lost-focus (122)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lost-focus)
- [alwaysontop (24)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alwaysontop) ⇒ [always-on-top (109)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/always-on-top)
- [hiddenfield (123)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hiddenfield) ⇒ [hidden-field (737)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-field)
- [sessionstorage (110)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sessionstorage) ⇒ [session-storage (306)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session-storage)
- [routedevents (15)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routedevents) ⇒ [routed-events (178)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routed-events)
- <s>[vuejs (322)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs) ⇒ [vue.js (3427)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js)</s> ([synonym request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357753/merge-vue-js-into-vuejs))
- [contenttype (78)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contenttype) ⇒ [content-type (1709)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-type)
- [eventreceiver (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventreceiver) ⇒ [event-receiver (126)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-receiver)
- [pdfviewer (67)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdfviewer) ⇒ [pdf-viewer (147)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf-viewer)
- <s>[keystonejs (340)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystonejs) ⇒ [keystone.js (340)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keystone.js)</s> ([synonym request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340262))
- [mvcminiprofiler (14)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvcminiprofiler) ⇒ [mvc-mini-profiler (362)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc-mini-profiler)

#### Only difference in the more popular (proposed target) having less punctuation

This could be a sign of not being ideal. The community needs to have a closer look.

- [log-files (30)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log-files) ⇒ [logfiles (199)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logfiles)
- [decimal-format (16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decimal-format) ⇒ [decimalformat (355)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decimalformat)
- [event-listener (97)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listener) ⇒ [eventlistener (740)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventlistener)
- [event-viewer (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-viewer) ⇒ [eventviewer (176)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventviewer)
- [last-insert-id (125)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/last-insert-id) ⇒ [lastinsertid (134)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lastinsertid)
- [pop-up (170)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pop-up) ⇒ [popup (7721)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popup)
- [asp.net-compiler (13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-compiler) ⇒ [aspnet-compiler (132)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspnet-compiler)
- [windows-forms-host (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms-host) ⇒ [windowsformshost (125)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsformshost)
- [single-instance (44)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-instance) ⇒ [singleinstance (152)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleinstance)
- [drop-shadow (29)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drop-shadow) ⇒ [dropshadow (237)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropshadow)
- [http-request (383)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-request) ⇒ [httprequest (4396)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httprequest)

#### Only difference in punctation kind

The respective technology communities have to decide.

- [settings-bundle (21)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings-bundle) ⇒ [settings.bundle (290)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings.bundle)
- [sqlite.net (69)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite.net) ⇒ [sqlite-net (285)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite-net)
- [web-config-transform (151)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-config-transform) ⇒ [web.config-transform (190)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web.config-transform)
- [boost.build (19)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost.build) ⇒ [boost-build (112)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-build)
- [info-plist (46)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/info-plist) ⇒ [info.plist (418)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/info.plist)
- [xamarin-forms (6184)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin-forms) ⇒ [xamarin.forms (6184)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms)

#### Pluralisation: proposed tag is plural

(I've ignored punctuation for these)

- [routedevent (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routedevent) ⇒ [routed-events (178)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routed-events)
- [typedarray (30)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typedarray) ⇒ [typed-arrays (172)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typed-arrays)
- [dynamicform (91)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamicform) ⇒ [dynamic-forms (162)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-forms)
- [viewhelper (58)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewhelper) ⇒ [view-helpers (358)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/view-helpers)
- [formhelper (139)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formhelper) ⇒ [form-helpers (284)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-helpers)
- [routedcommand (21)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routedcommand) ⇒ [routed-commands (142)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routed-commands)
- [metatag (65)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metatag) ⇒ [meta-tags (1616)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags)

#### Pluralisation: proposed tag is singular

(I've ignored punctuation for these)

- [ajax-forms (28)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax-forms) ⇒ [ajaxform (402)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxform)
- [menu-items (42)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu-items) ⇒ [menuitem (1918)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menuitem)
- [data-formats (45)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-formats) ⇒ [dataformat (143)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataformat)
- [event-listeners (242)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listeners) ⇒ [eventlistener (740)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventlistener)
- [web-user-controls (108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-user-controls) ⇒ [webusercontrol (247)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webusercontrol)
- [workflow-services (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workflow-services) ⇒ [workflowservice (147)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workflowservice)
- [tree-nodes (45)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree-nodes) ⇒ [treenode (500)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/treenode)
- [key-events (194)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key-events) ⇒ [keyevent (850)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyevent)
- [builtins (51)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/builtins) ⇒ [built-in (472)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in)
- [virtual-hosts (224)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-hosts) ⇒ [virtualhost (2101)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualhost)
- [mouse-listeners (138)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouse-listeners) ⇒ [mouselistener (936)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouselistener)
- [event-triggers (63)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-triggers) ⇒ [eventtrigger (441)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventtrigger)
- [data-members (58)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-members) ⇒ [datamember (149)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datamember)
- [bit-masks (45)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-masks) ⇒ [bitmask (441)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitmask)
- [log-files (30)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log-files) ⇒ [logfile (334)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logfile)
- [custom-validators (169)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-validators) ⇒ [customvalidator (381)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customvalidator)

#### Abbreviations

(i.e. everything shorter than 6 characters). It's usually a good thing they will get expanded.

- [clisp (309)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clisp) ⇒ [common-lisp (3741)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common-lisp)
- [args (441)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/args) ⇒ [arguments (6288)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arguments)
- [bll (106)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bll) ⇒ [business-logic-layer (198)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/business-logic-layer)
- [gcal (48)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcal) ⇒ [google-calendar (3637)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar)
- [cc (175)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cc) ⇒ [cross-compiling (2486)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-compiling)
- [fpc (1050)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fpc) ⇒ [freepascal (1050)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freepascal)
- [store (2273)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/store) ⇒ [storage (3741)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storage)
- [ipcs (22)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipcs) ⇒ [inter-process-communicat (3222)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inter-process-communicat)
- [yo (165)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yo) ⇒ [yeoman (2172)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yeoman)
- [sti (322)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sti) ⇒ [single-table-inheritance (497)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance)
- [hls (561)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hls) ⇒ [http-live-streaming (794)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-live-streaming)
- [ivar (133)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ivar) ⇒ [instance-variables (1071)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instance-variables)
- [udf (514)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udf) ⇒ [user-defined-functions (1834)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-defined-functions)
- [kvc (161)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kvc) ⇒ [key-value-coding (348)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/key-value-coding)
- [mq (651)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mq) ⇒ [message-queue (2470)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/message-queue)
- [fsm (335)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fsm) ⇒ [finite-state-machine (341)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finite-state-machine)
- [uia (25)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uia) ⇒ [ui-automation (1684)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui-automation)
- [ane (132)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ane) ⇒ [air-native-extension (281)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/air-native-extension)
- [edt (34)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edt) ⇒ [event-dispatch-thread (670)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread)
- [btle (51)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/btle) ⇒ [bluetooth-lowenergy (3949)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-lowenergy)
- [qsort (374)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qsort) ⇒ [quicksort (1770)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quicksort)
- [pch (95)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pch) ⇒ [precompiled-headers (293)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/precompiled-headers)
- [wmp (177)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wmp) ⇒ [windows-media-player (325)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-media-player)
- [hdd (115)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdd) ⇒ [hard-drive (576)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive)
- [apn (141)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apn) ⇒ [apple-push-notifications (5621)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-push-notifications)
- [mtm (141)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mtm) ⇒ [microsoft-test-manager (334)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-test-manager)
- [dih (136)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dih) ⇒ [dataimporthandler (333)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataimporthandler)
- [tvp (62)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tvp) ⇒ [table-valued-parameters (208)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-valued-parameters)
- [fab (214)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fab) ⇒ [floating-action-button (649)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-action-button)
- [rpt (32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpt) ⇒ [report (5198)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/report)
- [rte (212)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rte) ⇒ [rich-text-editor (665)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rich-text-editor)
- [osk (51)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osk) ⇒ [on-screen-keyboard (121)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/on-screen-keyboard)
- [tm (654)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tm) ⇒ [text-mining (1238)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-mining)
- [rr (27)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rr) ⇒ [rspec-rails (1506)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rspec-rails)
- [tmp (204)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tmp) ⇒ [temp (357)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temp)
- [fso (69)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fso) ⇒ [filesystemobject (209)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filesystemobject)
- [rdms (65)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdms) ⇒ [rdbms (1623)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdbms)
- [jil (24)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jil) ⇒ [jsonserializer (252)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonserializer)
- [dfs (388)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dfs) ⇒ [depth-first-search (837)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depth-first-search)
- [tph (59)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tph) ⇒ [table-per-hierarchy (107)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-per-hierarchy)

However there are also cases where the shorter one is more popular. These need to be carefully reviewed:

- [dynamic-html (83)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-html) ⇒ [dhtml (728)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dhtml)
- [access-point (113)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-point) ⇒ [apn (141)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apn)
- [er-diagram (36)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/er-diagram) ⇒ [erd (576)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erd)
- [square-root (218)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/square-root) ⇒ [sqrt (227)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqrt)
- [packet-capture (465)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/packet-capture) ⇒ [pcap (886)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcap)
- [oracle-service-bus (66)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-service-bus) ⇒ [osb (332)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osb)
- [rich-internet-application (117)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rich-internet-application) ⇒ [ria (860)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ria)
- [entity-sql (56)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-sql) ⇒ [esql (120)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esql)
- [json-web-token (173)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-web-token) ⇒ [jwt (2574)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jwt)
- [voicexml (108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/voicexml) ⇒ [vxml (140)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vxml)
- [libwww-perl (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libwww-perl) ⇒ [lwp (307)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lwp)
- [sql-server-data-tools (108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-data-tools) ⇒ [ssdt (915)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssdt)
- [self-organizing-maps (84)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-organizing-maps) ⇒ [som (118)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/som)
- [data-transfer-objects (105)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-transfer-objects) ⇒ [dto (982)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dto)
- [adobe-native-extensions (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-native-extensions) ⇒ [ane (132)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ane)
- [kernel-extension (34)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernel-extension) ⇒ [kext (196)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kext)
- [intermediate-language (93)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intermediate-language) ⇒ [il (1183)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/il)
- [portable-executable (180)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/portable-executable) ⇒ [pe (498)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pe)
- [end-of-line (90)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/end-of-line) ⇒ [eol (248)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eol)
- [quality-center (177)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quality-center) ⇒ [qc (228)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc)
- [access-point-name (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-point-name) ⇒ [apn (141)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apn)
- [elastic-map-reduce (444)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elastic-map-reduce) ⇒ [emr (884)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emr)
- [analog-digital-converter (61)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/analog-digital-converter) ⇒ [adc (195)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adc)
- [boost-jam (7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-jam) ⇒ [bjam (196)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bjam)
- [change-data-capture (93)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/change-data-capture) ⇒ [cdc (220)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdc)
- [process-control (32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/process-control) ⇒ [pcntl (136)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pcntl)
- [global-assembly-cache (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/global-assembly-cache) ⇒ [gac (929)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gac)
- [role-based-access-control (35)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/role-based-access-control) ⇒ [rbac (365)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rbac)
- [rational-team-concert (72)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rational-team-concert) ⇒ [rtc (394)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtc)
- [opendocument (69)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opendocument) ⇒ [odt (135)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odt)
- [topic-modeling (296)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topic-modeling) ⇒ [tm (654)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tm)
- [television (34)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/television) ⇒ [tv (295)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tv)
- [jexcelapi (181)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jexcelapi) ⇒ [jxl (392)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jxl)
- [advertisement (246)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advertisement) ⇒ [ads (1653)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ads)
- [over-the-air (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/over-the-air) ⇒ [ota (262)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ota)
- [embedded-ruby (54)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-ruby) ⇒ [erb (2013)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erb)
- [gwt-platform (244)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt-platform) ⇒ [gwtp (343)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwtp)
- [embedded-javascript (41)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-javascript) ⇒ [ejs (1442)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ejs)
- [accesscontrolservice (33)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accesscontrolservice) ⇒ [acs (373)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acs)
- [human-computer-interface (42)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/human-computer-interface) ⇒ [hci (111)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hci)
- [server-side-includes (215)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-side-includes) ⇒ [ssi (311)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssi)
- [virtualfilesystem (41)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualfilesystem) ⇒ [vfs (214)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vfs)
- [modified-preorder-tree-t (19)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modified-preorder-tree-t) ⇒ [mptt (114)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mptt)
- [er-diagrams (93)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/er-diagrams) ⇒ [erd (576)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erd)
- [io-completion-ports (58)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io-completion-ports) ⇒ [iocp (261)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iocp)
- [complex-event-processing (61)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complex-event-processing) ⇒ [cep (371)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cep)
- [winddk (161)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winddk) ⇒ [wdk (348)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wdk)
- [left-recursion (117)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/left-recursion) ⇒ [lr (125)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lr)
- [virtual-reality (153)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality) ⇒ [vr (494)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vr)
- [richtextediting (36)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/richtextediting) ⇒ [rte (212)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rte)
- [linux-containers (93)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-containers) ⇒ [lxc (382)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lxc)
- [gunzip (105)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gunzip) ⇒ [gz (230)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gz)
- [vertex-array-object (41)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vertex-array-object) ⇒ [vao (144)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vao)
- [content-delivery-network (30)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/content-delivery-network) ⇒ [cdn (1778)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdn)
- [command (6621)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command) ⇒ [cmd (13725)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd)

#### Angular(JS)

[Uh well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291426/1048572). [A constant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283216/1048572) [source of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309473/1048572) [annoyance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296857/1048572). Let's not discuss these here.

- [angularjs-google-maps (35)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-google-maps) ⇒ [angular-google-maps (309)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-google-maps)
- [angularjs-ng-if (36)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-if) ⇒ [angular-ng-if (335)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-if)
- [angularjs-templates (69)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-templates) ⇒ [angular-template (151)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-template)
- [angular-filters (573)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-filters) ⇒ [angularjs-filter (1025)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-filter)
- [angularjs-http (300)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-http) ⇒ [angular-http (438)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-http)
- [angular-module (74)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-module) ⇒ [angularjs-module (163)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-module)
- [angularjs-resource (272)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-resource) ⇒ [angular-resource (722)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-resource)
- [angularjs-bootstrap (95)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-bootstrap) ⇒ [angular-bootstrap (366)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-bootstrap)
- [angular-controller (240)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-controller) ⇒ [angularjs-controller (1094)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-controller)
- [angularjs-ng-model (359)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-model) ⇒ [angular-ngmodel (1031)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ngmodel)
- [angular-routing (927)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-routing) ⇒ [angularjs-routing (1198)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-routing)
- [angular-directive (878)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-directive) ⇒ [angularjs-directive (15481)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-directive)

#### The Rest.

I don't know what to do with these. Sorted by name for convenience so you may spot prefix patterns easily. Some comments inline.

- [abtest (35)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abtest) ⇒ [ab-testing (249)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ab-testing)
- [adaptor (55)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adaptor) ⇒ [adapter (3504)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adapter)
- [administrator (480)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administrator) ⇒ [administration (536)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administration)
- [ajaxuploader (16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxuploader) ⇒ [ajax-upload (106)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax-upload)
- [alassetlibrary (30)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alassetlibrary) ⇒ [alassetslibrary (618)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alassetslibrary)
- [android-internet (198)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-internet) ⇒ [android-intent (24007)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent)
- [application-bar (100)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-bar) ⇒ [appbar (231)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appbar)
- [application-data (43)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-data) ⇒ [appdata (202)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appdata)
- [applicationdomain (63)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applicationdomain) ⇒ [appdomain (1206)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appdomain)
- [appsettings (365)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appsettings) ⇒ [application-settings (651)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-settings)
- [audiorecord (315)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audiorecord) ⇒ [audio-recording (1477)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording)
- [audiostreamer (54)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audiostreamer) ⇒ [audio-streaming (1659)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio-streaming)
- [auto-rotation (114)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-rotation) ⇒ [autorotate (399)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autorotate)
- [automaton (77)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automaton) ⇒ [automata (363)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automata)
- [azure-management-api (77)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-management-api) ⇒ [azure-api-management (174)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-api-management)
- [azuread (199)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azuread) ⇒ [azure-active-directory (1589)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-active-directory)
- [backbone.js-collections (105)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone.js-collections) ⇒ [backbone-collections (392)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone-collections)
- [beizer (17)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beizer) ⇒ [bezier (526)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bezier) - a simple typo that should be burninated
- [blobstorage (107)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blobstorage) ⇒ [blobstore (797)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blobstore)
- [bulkloader (164)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bulkloader) ⇒ [bulk-load (194)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bulk-load)
- [cakephp-model (59)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-model) ⇒ [cakephp-appmodel (440)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cakephp-appmodel)
- [capture-group (84)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture-group) ⇒ [capturing-group (123)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capturing-group)
- [charts.js (125)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/charts.js) ⇒ [chart.js (2253)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chart.js)
- [checklistbox (87)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checklistbox) ⇒ [checkedlistbox (349)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checkedlistbox)
- [cleditor (67)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cleditor) ⇒ [ckeditor (6559)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ckeditor)
- [codesign (357)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codesign) ⇒ [code-signing (1710)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-signing)
- [collaborative (34)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collaborative) ⇒ [collaboration (424)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collaboration)
- [collapsable (141)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapsable) ⇒ [collapse (1109)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collapse)
- [communicate (97)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/communicate) ⇒ [communication (1953)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/communication)
- [coords (41)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coords) ⇒ [coordinates (3889)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coordinates)
- [covariant (51)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/covariant) ⇒ [covariance (1161)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/covariance)
- [customizing (74)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customizing) ⇒ [customization (3138)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/customization)
- [data-cleansing (200)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-cleansing) ⇒ [data-cleaning (264)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-cleaning)
- [data-storage (370)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-storage) ⇒ [datastore (480)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datastore)
- [database-connectivity (68)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-connectivity) ⇒ [database-connection (4763)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-connection)
- [database-link (71)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-link) ⇒ [dblink (255)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dblink)
- [date-difference (147)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-difference) ⇒ [datediff (896)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datediff)
- [datetime-parsing (81)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime-parsing) ⇒ [date-parsing (186)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-parsing)
- [dbconnection (126)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbconnection) ⇒ [database-connection (4763)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-connection)
- [dbproj (29)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbproj) ⇒ [database-project (494)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-project)
- [deeplink (60)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deeplink) ⇒ [deep-linking (1079)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-linking)
- [delimited (134)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delimited) ⇒ [delimiter (1649)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delimiter)
- [dimension-reduction (16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimension-reduction) ⇒ [dimensionality-reduction (139)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dimensionality-reduction)
- [disassembler (120)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disassembler) ⇒ [disassembly (382)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disassembly)
- [disassembly (382)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disassembly) ⇒ [disassembling (508)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disassembling)
- [distributed-cache (135)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distributed-cache) ⇒ [distributed-caching (301)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distributed-caching)
- [django-caching (37)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-caching) ⇒ [django-cache (144)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-cache)
- [django-mailer (33)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-mailer) ⇒ [django-email (114)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-email)
- [django-tagging (61)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-tagging) ⇒ [django-taggit (141)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-taggit)
- [django-tests (126)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-tests) ⇒ [django-testing (568)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-testing)
- [domready (108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/domready) ⇒ [document-ready (605)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/document-ready)
- [double-buffering (113)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double-buffering) ⇒ [doublebuffered (176)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doublebuffered)
- [dynamic-queries (85)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-queries) ⇒ [dynamicquery (166)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamicquery)
- [dynamic-usercontrols (63)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-usercontrols) ⇒ [dynamic-controls (287)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-controls)
- [emulation (364)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulation) ⇒ [emulator (2846)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emulator)
- [enumerator (285)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enumerator) ⇒ [enumeration (1349)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enumeration)
- [equality-operator (28)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equality-operator) ⇒ [equals-operator (132)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals-operator)
- [equivalence (122)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equivalence) ⇒ [equivalent (276)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equivalent)
- [evaluator (40)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluator) ⇒ [evaluation (715)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evaluation)
- [facebook-authorization (38)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-authorization) ⇒ [facebook-authentication (603)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-authentication)
- [file-read (281)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-read) ⇒ [filereader (1605)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filereader)
- [filebrowse (15)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filebrowse) ⇒ [file-browser (171)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-browser)
- [filehandle (290)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filehandle) ⇒ [file-handling (1173)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-handling)
- [form-authentication (190)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-authentication) ⇒ [forms-authentication (3006)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms-authentication)
- [formatted (63)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formatted) ⇒ [formatter (504)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formatter)
- [formsauthentication (110)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formsauthentication) ⇒ [form-authentication (190)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-authentication)
- [fulltext-index (70)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fulltext-index) ⇒ [full-text-indexing (388)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/full-text-indexing)
- [google-authenticator (94)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-authenticator) ⇒ [google-authentication (649)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-authentication)
- [google-closure-libraries (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-closure-libraries) ⇒ [google-closure-library (324)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-closure-library)
- [googlesigninaccount (38)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlesigninaccount) ⇒ [google-account (277)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-account)
- [googlesigninapi (50)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googlesigninapi) ⇒ [google-signin (1030)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-signin)
- [hextiles (21)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hextiles) ⇒ [hexagonal-tiles (121)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hexagonal-tiles)
- [initializing (66)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initializing) ⇒ [initialization (7153)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initialization)
- [integration-tests (78)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration-tests) ⇒ [integration-testing (3498)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration-testing)
- [interaction (445)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interaction) ⇒ [interactive (1004)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interactive)
- [interpreted (33)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpreted) ⇒ [interpreter (1481)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpreter)
- [ios-extensions (219)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-extensions) ⇒ [ios-app-extension (584)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-app-extension)
- [itemsource (85)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itemsource) ⇒ [itemssource (311)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itemssource)
- [jarsign (10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jarsign) ⇒ [jar-signing (182)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jar-signing)
- [jeasyui (63)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jeasyui) ⇒ [jquery-easyui (333)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-easyui)
- [jtemplates (44)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jtemplates) ⇒ [jquery-templates (744)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-templates)
- [keyevent (850)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyevent) ⇒ [keyboard-events (1313)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-events)
- [lazyload (54)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lazyload) ⇒ [lazy-loading (3188)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lazy-loading)
- [listview-adapter (112)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview-adapter) ⇒ [listadapter (899)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listadapter)
- [location-based-service (40)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/location-based-service) ⇒ [location-services (189)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/location-services)
- [maximization (34)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maximization) ⇒ [minimization (214)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minimization)
- [meteor-useraccounts (20)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor-useraccounts) ⇒ [meteor-accounts (586)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor-accounts)
- [migrating (66)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migrating) ⇒ [migration (6046)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration)
- [minmax (105)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minmax) ⇒ [minimax (407)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minimax)
- [mongo-java (231)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo-java) ⇒ [mongodb-java (778)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-java)
- [mongodb-shell (54)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb-shell) ⇒ [mongo-shell (212)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo-shell)
- [mpchart (63)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpchart) ⇒ [mpandroidchart (893)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpandroidchart)
- [multi-database (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-database) ⇒ [multiple-databases (420)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-databases)
- [multi-monitor (104)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-monitor) ⇒ [multiple-monitors (330)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors)
- [multi-table (95)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-table) ⇒ [multiple-tables (658)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-tables)
- [multifile (56)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multifile) ⇒ [multiple-files (338)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-files)
- [multiple-file-upload (97)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-file-upload) ⇒ [multifile-uploader (216)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multifile-uploader)
- [multiple-languages (111)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-languages) ⇒ [multilanguage (960)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilanguage)
- [multiple-processes (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-processes) ⇒ [multiprocess (206)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiprocess)
- [multiple-projects (113)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-projects) ⇒ [multi-project (204)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-project)
- [multiple-select (262)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-select) ⇒ [multi-select (1256)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-select)
- [multiple-users (78)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-users) ⇒ [multi-user (248)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-user)
- [multiple-value (98)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-value) ⇒ [multivalue (217)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multivalue)
- [multipleselection (212)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multipleselection) ⇒ [multiple-select (262)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiple-select)
- [nested-query (102)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-query) ⇒ [nested-queries (260)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nested-queries)
- [node-streams (46)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-streams) ⇒ [node.js-stream (137)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js-stream)
- [normalizing (26)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalizing) ⇒ [normalization (2134)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalization)
- [numberformatter (54)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numberformatter) ⇒ [number-formatting (1499)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/number-formatting)
- [numerics (48)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerics) ⇒ [numerical (479)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical)
- [options-menu (113)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options-menu) ⇒ [optionmenu (227)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optionmenu)
- [output-caching (34)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/output-caching) ⇒ [outputcache (629)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outputcache)
- [paginator (154)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginator) ⇒ [paginate (208)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginate)
- [paginator (154)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paginator) ⇒ [pagination (10865)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination)
- [performance-monitor (37)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance-monitor) ⇒ [perfmon (241)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perfmon)
- [persistent (587)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistent) ⇒ [persistence (3996)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/persistence)
- [poptoviewcontroller (66)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poptoviewcontroller) ⇒ [popviewcontroller (121)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/popviewcontroller)
- [powermanager (81)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powermanager) ⇒ [power-management (413)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/power-management)
- [pyunit (138)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyunit) ⇒ [python-unittest (788)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-unittest)
- [qwebkit (136)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qwebkit) ⇒ [qtwebkit (622)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtwebkit)
- [ratelimit (41)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratelimit) ⇒ [rate-limiting (245)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rate-limiting)
- [rdebug (15)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdebug) ⇒ [ruby-debug (146)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-debug)
- [refcounting (39)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refcounting) ⇒ [reference-counting (297)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reference-counting)
- [referer (168)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/referer) ⇒ [referrer (457)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/referrer)
- [router (1645)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/router) ⇒ [routes (9863)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routes)
- [schtasks (71)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schtasks) ⇒ [scheduled-tasks (4164)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheduled-tasks)
- [scriplets (78)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scriplets) ⇒ [scriptlet (263)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scriptlet)
- [sencha-command (25)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sencha-command) ⇒ [sencha-cmd (380)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sencha-cmd)
- [singlepage (203)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singlepage) ⇒ [single-page-application (2375)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-page-application)
- [skimage (108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skimage) ⇒ [scikit-image (315)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scikit-image)
- [speechsynthesizer (45)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speechsynthesizer) ⇒ [speech-synthesis (249)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speech-synthesis)
- [static-initializer (66)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-initializer) ⇒ [static-initialization (190)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-initialization)
- [subdirectories (288)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectories) ⇒ [subdirectory (610)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subdirectory)
- [synchronisation (77)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronisation) ⇒ [synchronization (9075)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronization)
- [syntaxhighlighter (138)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntaxhighlighter) ⇒ [syntax-highlighting (2548)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting)
- [system-administration (258)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system-administration) ⇒ [sysadmin (412)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sysadmin)
- [systray (81)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systray) ⇒ [system-tray (512)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system-tray)
- [tabbed-view (42)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabbed-view) ⇒ [tabview (336)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabview)
- [templating-engine (67)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templating-engine) ⇒ [template-engine (1457)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-engine)
- [topicmodels (27)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topicmodels) ⇒ [topic-modeling (296)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topic-modeling)
- [transactional (563)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transactional) ⇒ [transactions (10809)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transactions)
- [transparent (1523)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transparent) ⇒ [transparency (2775)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transparency)
- [uisearchbardisplaycontrol (72)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uisearchbardisplaycontrol) ⇒ [uisearchdisplaycontroller (824)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uisearchdisplaycontroller)
- [va-arg (100)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/va-arg) ⇒ [varargs (780)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/varargs)
- [validating (109)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validating) ⇒ [validation (46826)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validation)
- [virtual-hosts (224)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-hosts) ⇒ [vhosts (700)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhosts)
- [visual-studio-code (2888)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) ⇒ [vscode (2888)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode)
- [visual-studio-package (32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-package) ⇒ [vspackage (327)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vspackage)
- [webdeploy (857)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdeploy) ⇒ [web-deployment (2261)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-deployment)
- [webservices-client (237)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webservices-client) ⇒ [webservice-client (944)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webservice-client)
- [webtest (229)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webtest) ⇒ [web-testing (328)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-testing)
- [winapp (70)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapp) ⇒ [windows-applications (942)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-applications)
- [window-messages (59)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window-messages) ⇒ [windows-messages (235)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-messages)
- [window-server (54)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window-server) ⇒ [windows-server (539)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-server)
- [windowsformhost (27)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsformhost) ⇒ [windowsformshost (125)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windowsformshost)
- [word-boundaries (24)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-boundaries) ⇒ [word-boundary (113)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-boundary)
- [writablebitmap (46)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writablebitmap) ⇒ [writeablebitmap (255)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writeablebitmap)
- [xmldoc (52)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmldoc) ⇒ [xml-documentation (244)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-documentation) - nah, doc can also refer to document
- [xmldom (198)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmldom) ⇒ [xmldocument (947)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmldocument) - nah, the document model is not the same as a single document

Comment: Now we have to edit 2 lists..

Comment: Many of these seem fine by the community. But noone ever went ahead and actually did these, right? Can someone with rep go ahead and close [tag:lazyload] ⇒ [tag:lazy-loading] please?

Comment: "Only difference in the more popular (proposed target) having more punctuation - This is usually a good thing." No it isn't the only difference, and not so fast. 'builtin' (116) is a keyword in Python 3 and __builtin__ in Python 2 so don't do ⇒ 'built-in' (472)

Comment: @smci Sure, feel free to add a comment in the list or remove from that section. Didn't I make this answer community-wiki?