# Make the synonym system more available

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

[The appalling number of missing tag synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342097/a-list-of-tag-synonyms-which-are-not-proposed-in-stack-overflow) and [unfulfilled synonym and other retag requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%28+%5Bsynonym-request%5D+or+%5Bretag-request%5D%29+score%3A20+hasaccepted%3Ano+closed%3Ano+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D) with no signs of improvement shows that the current synonym mechanic fails to create a working system that would allow interested parties to get tag managements tasks done.

I'm hereby asking for feedback on the ideas to fix that that I have (will post them as an answer) as well as polling for other options.

Comment: [Give Tag synonyms their own review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202754). [Does the tag synonym suggestion system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127459)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ideas I currently have are:

- Make more users eligible for tag managements tasks

  - [Count acceptance marks towards tag score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314797/should-accept-marks-count-towards-the-tag-score), or
  - Remove the tag score requirement entirely as proven too restrictive (possibly adjusting reputation requirement to compensate)

    - For many (most?) tags, too few active users are eligible under the current system to get anything done
    - This is in line with other site mechanics: no other site management tasks -- *including tag management tasks:* creating, editing tags on questions, editing tag descriptions (=scope) -- have any tag-related requirements whatsoever
- Make tag managements tasks more visible to eligible users

  - A review queue could be used for that, but unless the tag score requirement is lifted, it has to be much more prominent than a review queue -- something like a notification in the top panel. Because very few active users are eligible for most such tasks, it has to be very prominent to allow enough qualified users to see a request within a reasonable time.

Comment: *Count acceptance marks towards tag score* I would not like to see this.  The accepted mark isn't really a measure on the "goodness" of the answer.  All it signals is that the OP liked it (and remember most OP's aren't the best people to judge what is correct).  I've seen some pretty bad accepted answers

Comment: I do like the idea to just make it a rep based privilege though.

Comment: @NathanOliver See the link to that suggestion for the rationale behind it and the previous discussion. Those arguments were already sounded.

Comment: After a lot of time, nothing else was suggested, so I'm accepting this.