# Replace tag score requirement with reputation requirement to suggest and/or vote for tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, voting, tag-synonym-process

Due to a favorable reception of [Make the synonym system more available](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374054/make-the-synonym-system-more-available), I'm now making a concrete suggestion of one of the ideas sounded in it (see the link for rationale):

- **Remove the tag score requirement for suggesting and/or voting on tag synonyms as proven too restrictive, possibly adjusting reputation requirement to compensate.**

*Details still to flesh out are:*

- Whether the reputation requirement for: 1) suggesting a synonym; and 2) voting on a synonym -- needs to be adjusted, and by how much.

  [Currently, the former is 2'500, and the latter appears to be none (!)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) (I can't verify that though)

Comment: The tag score requirement should definitely be lifted. I faced the problem where a rarely used tag is actually the correct one. I had to request that the more popular tag become a synonym for the rare one, but I had no rep for it. So I had to resort to retagging a question where I had rep, then waiting a couple of days for the system to register that now I do have rep on the rare tag.