# Synonomize [typelib] and [type-library]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tag [typelib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typelib) means "type library", and its definition includes that term. "Typelib" isn't just an abbreviation, it is the actual name as given by Microsoft, and used in virtually all technical documentation.

The other tag [type-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-library) should be made the secondary tag, pointing to typelib. Scanning through many of the questions using it, they seem to be mainly about the Windows / COM technologies.

I see this has been caught by the automated script in [A list of tag synonyms which are not proposed in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342097/a-list-of-tag-synonyms-which-are-not-proposed-in-stack-overflow). But nothing has been done yet.

Comment: `typelib`  does have special significance. It is jargon for COM programming on Windows. That’s why the tag exists. Now, that said, a typelib is still a type library, so a synonym may still be appropriate.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm familiar with that usage but I always thought it was just a common abbreviation, and not a technical term specific to the Windows / COM usage.

Comment: It isn’t just a “common” abbreviation. It is an official one. It is the actual name as given by Microsoft, and used in virtually all technical documentation. If you called it a “type library”, I’d have to think a half of a second to realize what you meant. If you called it a TypeLib, I’d know immediately (especially if you spoke it with the CamelCase).

Comment: @CodyGray funny in my head I always pronounce "TLB" as "typelib" and never really wrote it out! lol.  Updated the question to reflect your input. Thanks

Comment: There are 38 questions related to Delphi with the tag [tag:type-library] here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-library+delphi. Are you sure that these questions are related to the same topic as what [tag:typelib] posts are about? If yes, then let me know, and I'll synonymize the two tags.

Comment: @BhargavRao as far as I know Delphi is built on or at least is commonly integrated with the same COM tech as VB6. Scanning through the questions tagged in your list, they seem like exactly the same sort of topics to me.

Comment: Pinged a Delphi dev here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/45616032#45616032, to confirm once.

Comment: @BhargavRao Those Delphi questions fall into the same category... type-library typelib it is all about the same technology... Official Delphi documentation uses term ["Type Library"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Type_Library_(Delphi)), but we all call it typelib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Cody (who is also a top user in this tech), clearly mentions in the comments,  synonymizing it in the other direction would be a better option here because "typelib" the official, most recognizable term. Dalija, another top user in [delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi), which is one of the top related tags, [has also confirmed that the synonyms make sense](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379779/synonomize-typelib-and-type-library?noredirect=1#comment677106_379779).

There was one issue: during the [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags), the tag, [typelibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typelibrary) was added as a synonym to [type-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-library). As Stack Overflow does not allow chaining of synonyms, we had to first break the synonym and then re-add the two tags as synonyms. I did this and added those as synonyms. The scenario now is:

[typelib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typelib) × 106 ←   [typelibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typelibrary) × 17
[typelib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typelib) × 106 ←   [type-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-library) × 162

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking care of this and driving the input & process to do it.