# Synonymize tags [multi-factor] and [multi-factor-authentication]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tag description for [multi-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor) is:

> Use for questions about multi-factor authentication (MFA). MFA is a way to secure access to a resource by requiring a user to provide multiple pieces of evidence of identity. These pieces of evidence are called factors. Typically, a user will be required to provide a least two factors of the following types: knowledge (something the user knows); possession (something the user has), and inherence (something the user is).

The tag description for [multi-factor-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor-authentication) is:

> An authentication system is responsible to tell if the user is who they claim to be. A multi-factor uses multiple factors to check that claim.

There are 62 questions tagged [multi-factor-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor-authentication) and 82 tagged [multi-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor), and 5 of those are tagged with both tags (so there 139 distinct questions).

There's little doubt in my mind that these refer to the same concept and should be synonyms.  I think it would be better to make [multi-factor-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor-authentication) into the master (official) tag and have [multi-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor) as a synonym for it.  However, the description associated with [multi-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor) is arguably better.

These tags are not included in the monster list of possible tag synonyms in [A list of tag synonyms which are not proposed in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342097/a-list-of-tag-synonyms-which-are-not-proposed-in-stack-overflow).

---

There's also a tag [two-factor-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/two-factor-authentication) with 358 questions.  Of those, there are 7 which are also tagged with [multi-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor), 4 which are also tagged with [multi-factor-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor-authentication) and there are 2 questions with all three tags.  It has a moderately good tag description.  It also cross-references the [Security Stack Exchange `[multi-factor]`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor) tag, which has over 500 questions.

I think that [two-factor-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/two-factor-authentication) should also be synonymized with [multi-factor-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor-authentication).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the 87 questions tagged [multi-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor), and two of them were about [multifactorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials). I replaced the tag from those two and added [multi-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor) as a synonym for [multi-factor-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor-authentication), that is:

[multi-factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor) (× 85) → [multi-factor-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor-authentication) (× 79)

I also found another tag, [mfa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mfa) that had 147 questions, all of them which were about Multi Factor Authentication. Given that the [mfa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mfa) tag, 1. didn't have an tag synonym 2. didn't have a descriptive name, I chose [multi-factor-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor-authentication) as the master. The synonym order is now:

[mfa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mfa) (× 147) → [multi-factor-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor-authentication) (× 79)

I'll wait a few days and then merge the tags.

Comment: Thanks for the work checking for 'multifactorials' — and for synonymizing the tags.

Answer (score 2):

They should all be merged under one tag.