# Merge [menu-items] into [menuitem]

Tags: support, retag-request

[menuitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menuitem) and [menu-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu-items) have identical tag wikis, but the former has (as of writing) been used 2,382 times and the latter 94 times. Let's merge [menu-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu-items) into [menuitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menuitem).

Comment: This [has been discussed long ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fmenu-items) here: [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251478/4642212) and here: [A list of tag synonyms which are not proposed in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342097/4642212). It’s in the list of _“Tag pairs that cannot be created due to other conflicting synonym proposals”_ and has the annotation “synonym conflict”. Not sure what that means; probably there’s an active synonym proposal that conflicts this somehow.

Comment: Because [tag:menuitem] is currently proposed to be a tag synonym for [tag:menu]. Here is [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1263219/tags-and-their-wikis-and-excerpts-that-are-similar-to-tag-name?tag=menuitem&starts=1) I use when evaluating tag synonyms. To free up the tag, at least 3 users with score of >= 5 in it are needed. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/menu/synonyms

Comment: Frankly speaking, I do not see any merit in keeping either of the tags around - they should probably be synonymized to [tag:menu]. Menu items are not standalone entities - every question about menu items is also a question about menus. I could go as far as to say that it is usually about CSS, HTML, JavaScript, Bootstrap, and so on and is hardly about menu items per se.

Comment: @OlegValter Great idea. [Posted.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405702/5306507)