# Merge all generic menu-related tags

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

| Tag | Questions |
| --- | --- |
| [menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu) | ‌15044 |
| [menu-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu-items) | ‌ 94 |
| [menuitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menuitem) | ‌ 2384 |
| [submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/submenu) | ‌ 1349 |

[Trying to sort out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405629/merge-menu-items-into-menuitem) if a submenu is a menuitem or if menu-items constitute a menu, etc. can be complicated, and efforts are currently blocked by conflicting synonym proposals. To cut the Gordian knot, I propose simple merging them all into a single generic [menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu) tag.

Comment: At the very least, [[tag:menu-items]] and [[tag:menuitem]] should be merged. They both have the exact same description *"A menu item is a child element of a menu that provides the user a means to view and execute a specific application operation"*

Comment: I strongly suggest adding a link to your previous Meta post for additional context. Otherwise, as the comment by Tomerikoo indicates, users are going to end up covering the same ground again.

Comment: @Tomerikoo - yeah, they should, but they can't :( [rehashing the comment I made earlier - agreed with cigien] Either a mod needs to interfere, or we have to find 3 users to stop the synonym merge to [tag:menu] (or 3 more to approve). There is a synonym conflict.

Comment: @OlegValter oh thanks I wasn't aware of that. In that case - any *menu* experts in the crowd? ;)

Comment: @Tomerikoo - nope, not a single question answered :) What's more, we specifically need experts on [tag:menu-items] and [tag:submenu]...

Comment: We should probably also take a look whether it makes sense to add [tag:menubar] to the list, as well as [tag:menuitem-selection] (whatever this beast is - does anyone have a clue?)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the proposal: all the other tags except for [menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu) represent menu constituents and rarely make sense without the main tag.

There is, however, a concern, that when the main tag is not used, it is usually substituted by a technology-specific tag like [android-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-menu) or [aspmenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspmenu).

These tags, in general, mean one thing: "menus in {{technology here}}" (see excerpts: "menus and action bars in Android", "menus for ASP.NET Web forms") and can be broken into `[language-tag] + [menu]` pairs without the loss in meaning (and they usually are, for example, the [android-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-menu) is used alongside [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)).

For this reason and because it is highly likely the merged tags will be recreated given the extensive usage (no less than 5K questions total), it is proposed to:

> synonymize all of them to the [menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu) tag

Given the coordination of a single synonym vote is usually a non-trivial action, it is preferrable if a moderator takes action if there are no objections (which seems to be the case as the request is nearly a month old).

That said, if anyone is interested and has a score in [menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menu) needed (>= 5) to vote for synonyms, there are 2 pending requests ([menuitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menuitem) and [submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/submenu)) that need 3 more such users to cast their vote on the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/menu/synonyms) page.