# To dot or not to dot that is the [pdfjs] question, or is it [pdf.js]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

> Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
> The slings and arrows of outrageous naming
> Or to take Arms against a Sea of tags 'n users
> And by opposing, burninate them.

Okay, so there are two tags, [pdfjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdfjs) and [pdf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf.js). The wikis both refer to the same product: the library whose source code is located at GitHub here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js.

All of the references to the library I've seen (from Mozilla), its name has been spelled "pdf.js" or "PDF.js". So the dot is in the name.

Also, [pdf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdf.js) (743 questions) was created two years before [pdfjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdfjs) (413 questions).

The two tags were on [A list of tag synonyms which are not proposed in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342097/215552)

Comment: What's in a name? That which we call a rose by any other name would smell as sweet.

Comment: @Ghengistom: or is it rose.js?